# Why SQL Server DATETIME type saves time in ticks of 1/300 of a sec?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sybase, history

SQLServer datetime format is stored as 8 bytes where the first four bytes are number of days since Jan 1, 1900 and the other four bytes are number of ticks since midnight. And the tick is 1/300 of the second.

I'm wondering why is that? Where is that 1/300 came from? There must be some historic reason for that.

Comment: I've often wondered why the closest to midnight you could get was 23:59:59.997.

Comment: @Jonathan - Which is usually a good indication that you should be using an exclusive endpoint (i.e. midnight of the following day) when working with datetime data and wanting a complete day's worth - if you've hardcoded the `997` or used other tricks to calculate it, you'll have to change all of your code if you shift to `datetime2`.

Comment: It goes back to Sybase days. The maximum 32 bit signed int would allow precision up to 24,855 ticks per second so I wondered about that too.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is a historical reason: UNIX !

For details, read this [excelent article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/contiguous-time-periods/)  by Joe Celko.

Here is the detail you're looking for:

> Temporal data in T-SQL
>   used to be a **prisoner of UNIX system clock ticks** and could only go
>   to three decimal seconds with rounding errors. The new ANSI/ISO data
>   types can go to seven decimal seconds, have a true DATE and TIME data
>   types. Since they are new, most programmers are not using them yet.

Comment: Is he saying that Unix also only had 300 ticks per second? Or just that both use the concept of a tick?

Comment: It is about the old resolution of the first unix internal clocks - has nothing to do wbout how they ticked, just how their time resolution was. Sql server has quite a lot of old unix (sybase) ancestory, just check the timestamp column that has no timestamp at all ;)