# SQL Server milliseconds always end in 0, 3 and 7

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Why does the millisecond portion of a MS SQL Server `DateTime` data type always end in 0, 3 or 7?  I've hit F5 on a `SELECT GetDate()` numerous times, and the milliseconds consistently end in one of those three numbers.

To demonstrate, I've made this example, with the results below:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (dt DateTime)
DECLARE @i INT = 1
WHILE @i <= 2000
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @t(dt) VALUES(GetDate())
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END
SELECT DISTINCT dt FROM @t
```

> ```
> 2016-08-05 15:38:06.380
> 2016-08-05 15:38:06.383
> 2016-08-05 15:38:06.420
> 2016-08-05 15:38:06.630
> 2016-08-05 15:38:06.817
> 2016-08-05 15:38:07.053
> 2016-08-05 15:38:07.057
> 2016-08-05 15:38:07.230
> 2016-08-05 15:38:07.233
> 2016-08-05 15:38:07.453
> 2016-08-05 15:38:07.457
> 2016-08-05 15:38:07.510
> 2016-08-05 15:38:07.570
> 2016-08-05 15:38:07.623
> 2016-08-05 15:38:07.690
> 2016-08-05 15:38:07.693
> 2016-08-05 15:38:07.747
> 2016-08-05 15:38:07.750
> 2016-08-05 15:38:07.800
> 2016-08-05 15:38:07.803
> 2016-08-05 15:38:07.857
> 2016-08-05 15:38:07.910
> 2016-08-05 15:38:07.913
> 2016-08-05 15:38:07.967
> 2016-08-05 15:38:07.970
> 2016-08-05 15:38:08.027
> 2016-08-05 15:38:08.080
> 2016-08-05 15:38:08.130
> ```

Comment: Is the thousands place of this number even considered to be significant?

Comment: Interesting observation, I am wondering that now as well

Comment: **tl;dr**: use `datetime2`. @lucas no need to wonder; it was already answered before you commented.

Comment: This answer seems to be a duplicate of [question 21825615](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825615/why-sql-server-datetime-type-saves-time-in-ticks-of-1-300-of-a-sec). TL; DR: SQL Server is based on Sybase, and Sybase's datetimes were made the way they were due to Unix