# MYSQL get latest job number

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have this table:

```
TableNumber(Int 0 to 25)|Name(varchar 100)|Project(varchar 15)|StartDate(Datetime)
1                       |David            |P1                 |'2015-02-06 08:00:00'    
2                       |Sebastien        |P2                 |'2015-02-06 08:00:00'    
1                       |David            |P4                 |'2015-02-06 12:00:00'    
2                       |Sebastien        |P3                 |'2015-02-07 08:00:00'
```

And I am looking to get the latest job for each person on a set day.

I would like to have:

```
TableNumber(Int 0 to 25)|Name(varchar 100)|Project(varchar 15)|StartDate(Datetime)    
2                       |Sebastien        |P2                 |'2015-02-06 08:00:00'    
1                       |David            |P4                 |'2015-02-06 12:00:00'
```

So I want to exclude P3 since its not '2015-02-06' and I want to exclude P1 cause its not the latest job for David (its P4).

Please consider that NOW() returns '2015-02-06 15:00:00' in the following exemples.

Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE DATEDIFF(startdate, NOW()) = 0 ORDER BY tablenum DESC;
```

But this only excluded P3

So I tried this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable AS p WHERE DATEDIFF(p.startdate, NOW()) = 0 AND TIMEDIFF(p.startdate, NOW()) = (SELECT MAX(TIMEDIFF(p2.startdate, NOW())) FROM MyTable AS p2 WHERE p2.startdate = p.startdate) ORDER BY tablenum DESC;
```

But Its still doesn't exclude P1.

Anyone know how I could achieve this? BTW startdate will always be a round hour (08:00:00 or 12:00:00 or 22:00:00...)

**UPDATE**

Yeah since it wasn't very clear what I wanted I will clarify here:

I need to know the last project worked on by every person.

so in my table I need to know that Sebastien work on P2 on table number 2 and that David work on P4 on table number 1. I don't want P1 because its not the last project that David worked on (by last project I also include the project he is working on right now). I also want to rule out everything in the future so P3 (who is tomorrow) must not display.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Comment: `select user, max(startdate) ... group by user`?

Comment: By latest, I understood the the "most late" project (from the context of your question)

Comment: On a set day, do you mean that as of a given date/time what were the jobs in incurred the most delays for each name? Or do you mean to find the earliest job on a given day for each name?

Comment: Your name and your spelling of "example" seems to indicate you are French.

Comment: @Tarik Yeah sorry for the spelling errors... My english is a bit rusty since I don't live in the english speaking part of Canada anymore

Comment: @Sebastien Have been there :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query will provide you with the date/time of the earliest job for a given name on a given day. In the following example I assumed you want the earliest jobs of each user on 2015-02-06.

```
SELECT Name, min(StartDate)
FROM MyTable
WHERE StartDate >= '2015-02-06'
  AND StartDate < '2015-02-07'
GROUP BY Name
```

Using the above query, you can trivially get the final solution:

```
SELECT t1.project, t2.name, t2.StartDate
FROM MyTable t1 INNER JOIN
   (SELECT Name, min(StartDate)
FROM MyTable
WHERE StartDate >= '2015-02-06'
  AND StartDate < '2015-02-07'
GROUP BY Name) t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name AND t1.StartDate = t2.StartDate
```

Comment: You need to return the project name too

Comment: @Tarik Well actually your first query worked just fine I changed the MIN for MAX and everything seams to work properly

Comment: @Tarik Here is the final query that works: 'SELECT tablenum, name, project, MAX(StartDate) AS date
FROM MyTable
WHERE DATEDIFF(startdate, NOW()) = 0 GROUP BY name order by tablenum desc;

Comment: Clarifying your question will help me revise my answer to meet your needs.

Comment: @Sebastien: Using DATEDIFF will prevent an index from being used on the WHERE clause, forcing a full table scan every time this query is run.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547316/is-sql-datediffyear-an-expensive-computation  You should either add logic to generate less-than-greater-than logic like Tarik used above or add a column to your table that is only the date part of the timestamp and search for an exact match.  Otherwise, you will see scalability problems going forward.