# Slow Running Update of large table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an update on SQL Server that is taking a long time to run. The code is below:

```
update
     f
    set
     f.WorkKey = d.WorkKey,
     f.LastModifiedDtm = GETDATE()
    from
     f_cic_i_agent_queue f
    join
     NMWork d
    on
     f.Workgroup = d.WorkCode
    and
     f.NOMDate >= d.StartDate and
     (f.NOMDate <= d.EndDate or d.EndDate is null)
    where
     datediff(mm,f.NOMDate,getdate()) <= 18
```

I suspect it is that last "or" statement. There is a clustered composite primary key index which includes the NOMDate and Workgroup fields among others.

Was is the best way to optimize this update statement?

Comment: questions seeking performance help should include DDL,DML Of the tables involved along with test data..if your test data is large,try scripting out schema and stats for the table(right click database->generate scripts->select specific database objects->in next screen select advanced and choose Script statistics) and paste it in question..With this info any one repro the same issue you are facing.Otherwise it becomes very difficult to answer your question .Pasting server version also helps

Comment: You need to provide execution plan and index information. Before that you can try avoiding DateDiff in where clause. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547316/is-sql-datediffyear-an-expensive-computation

Answer (score 0):

change your where statment

```
update
     f
    set
     f.WorkKey = d.WorkKey,
     f.LastModifiedDtm = GETDATE()
    from
     f_cic_i_agent_queue f
    join
     NMWork d
    on
     f.Workgroup = d.WorkCode
    and
     f.NOMDate >= d.StartDate and
     (f.NOMDate <= d.EndDate or d.EndDate is null)
    where
     f.NOMDate>dateadd(mm,-18,getdate())
```

Or even better, use a local var to hold dateadd(mm,-18,getdate())