# How do I get just the date when using MSSQL GetDate()?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

```
DELETE from Table WHERE Date > GETDATE();
```

GETDATE() includes time.  Instead of getting

```
2011-01-26 14:58:21.637
```

How can I get:

```
2011-01-26 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Also, consider that you might want `>=` rather than `>`, or you'll actually miss out on deleting records that are exactly 2011-01-26 00:00:00.000...

Comment: Good call, I actually changed that before reading this comment :)

Comment: A simple solution would be `cast(left(getdate(), 11) as datetime)`

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Slight bias to SQL Server

- [Best approach to remove time part of datetime in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server/1177529#1177529)
- [Most efficient way in SQL Server to get date from date+time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133081/most-efficient-way-in-sql-server-to-get-date-from-datetime)

Summary

```
DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

SQL Server 2008 has `date` type though.  So just use

```
CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Edit: To add one day, compare to the day before "zero"

```
DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, -1, GETDATE()), 0)
```

From cyberkiwi:

An alternative that does not involve 2 functions is (the +1 can be in or ourside the brackets).

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE() +1)
```

`DateDiff` returns a number but for all purposes this will work as a date wherever you intend to use this expression, except converting it to VARCHAR directly - in which case you would have used the CONVERT approach directly on GETDATE(), e.g.

```
convert(varchar, GETDATE() +1, 102)
```

Comment: How do I add one day to this value?

Comment: select CAST(GETDATE() + 1 AS DATE)

Comment: @eidgenossen: Simple, but relies on an implicit conversion. Less clear.

Answer (score 11):

For SQL Server 2008, the best and index friendly way is

```
DELETE from Table WHERE Date > CAST(GETDATE() as DATE);
```

For prior SQL Server versions, date maths will work faster than a convert to varchar.  Even converting to varchar can give you the wrong result, because of regional settings.

```
DELETE from Table WHERE Date > DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE());
```

<sub>Note: it is unnecessary to wrap the `DATEDIFF` with another `DATEADD`</sub>

Comment: The "older" style without DATEADD relies on implicit conversion from int to date based on [precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx). This is effectively DATEADD in practice, no? I prefer explicit conversions myself, even though this looks cleaner.

Comment: Not sure how QO goes about it, but there is no reason to manually request a DATEADD. Even though the datatype is datetime, `internally` when comparing, it is converted to a numeric value, so it may be better to just leave it just as an int.

Answer (score 6):

It's database specific. You haven't specified what database engine you are using.

e.g. in PostgreSQL you do cast(myvalue as date).

Comment: You mean GETDATE() is not enough of a clue?

Comment: I think the OP said "MSSQL"

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 101))
```

Comment: It determines the format of the output string, in this case mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.  Hence the varchar(10) which truncates the time portion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
DELETE from Table WHERE Date > CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 101);
```

Comment: That returns a string. Best not to rely on implicit conversion. Instead, cast it to a date or date/time explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

```
CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),102)
```

Comment: The 101, 102, etc, are just parameters for the CONVERT function.  I believe you might actually want to use 101 which is in the form of mm/dd/yyyy, while 102 is in the form mm.dd.yyyy I believe...

Comment: That returns a string.  Instead of relying on implicit conversion, best to cast it to a date explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

Here you have few solutions ;)

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/122-Getting-Only-the-Date-Part-of-a-Date-Time-Stamp-in-SQL-Server.htm

Comment: Sorry, but that link is incomplete: it doesn't consider the dateadd/datediff technique