# Same SQL works on one machine but gives out-of-range error on another

Tags: sql

`The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.`

When I run the SQL query on my desktop machine, its fine.  No errors or anything.  However, when I execute the same code on the server that will be running it, it fails.

I've determined this is the section of SQL causing the issue.  DateOfRun is a DateTime field.

```
 ,(SELECT intField
    FROM tableA
    WHERE RowIdentifier= ParentTable.RowIdentifier
            AND DateOfRun = Convert(Varchar(10),ParentTable.OfferOutcomeDateTime,120)) AS Days
```

Why would this work on one machine, but not the other?

Comment: Why are you converting a `DateTime` field to a `varchar` and then comparing it to another `DateTime`?

Comment: Because DateOfRun doesn't have a time, where as OfferOutcome does.  00:00:00 <> 14:23:22

Comment: My guess is he is attempting to shear off the time component

Comment: It shouldn't work on either of them. The SQL makes no sense, as Adam mentioned (converting a `DateTime` to a `Varchar(10)` and then comparing to a `DateTime`) - in addition, using `AS Days` in a `WHERE` clause isn't valid SQL AFAIK either.

Comment: Converting to varchar is **bad**. Use date math like DateDiff and DateAdd. Or convert to a data type that doesn't have time. Or tell us your DBMS so we can give you specifics. Actually, you shouldn't even be converting, you should use a range expression instead.

Comment: @billinkc: If he were using `101`, I would buy that. But `120` gives you the ODBC canonical format (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), which includes the time.

Comment: @adam: It doesn't matter if you use 101 or 120

Comment: @Matt: `120` includes the time. The only reason you aren't getting the time in your case is because the size of your target (`varchar(10)`) is not long enough to hold it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's definitively odd and likely to do with regional settings but its like the old joke

> A man goes to a doctor's office. He
>   says, "Doctor, it hurts when I raise
>   my arm over my head." The doctor
>   replies, "Then don't raise your arm
>   over your head."

So don't do that. Do this instead

```
WHERE RowIdentifier= ParentTable.RowIdentifier
          AND DateOfRun = 
           DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, ParentTable.OfferOutcomeDateTime), 0)
```

Its the best way to go see Thomas' answer to [Most efficient way in SQL Server to get date from date+time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133081/most-efficient-way-in-sql-server-to-get-date-from-datetime)

Then it will work regardless of regional settings because it never gets represented as a string

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that DateTime conversion from string fails because of different cultures on the local and server environments.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention your flavour of SQL, but the most likely candidate is a discrepancy between the input format of the char field and the system's locale settings.

"3/30/2011" is the 30th of March in the US, but makes no sense in the UK.
"30/3/2011" is the 30th of March in the UK, but makes no sense in the US.

Answer (score 0):

This would work on one machine and not the other if the data is different on the different machines.

It would also not work if your regional settings are different.

You should do something like
`SET DATEFORMAT dmy` to set the format you want to use.

You could also convert/cast your date to local settings before you convert it to a varchar - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Converting to varchar is bad. Instead use date math.