# sql select datetime stamp as m/d/y only. (without h m s)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

When I select two rows with a DATETEIME stamp, I only want the m/d/y data and nothing after that.

It has to changed during the select (not afterwards).

Comment: TSQL is used by both SQL Server and Sybase -- which is it?  It can drastically impact the answer.

Comment: Do you only want the date component of the date, or are you trying to format a string right in the query?

Comment: Assuming SQL Server, majority of the native TSQL options are done via [CAST/CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) if not crafting by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this for export? If you only want the text you can use a variety of coversion formats available [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 101)
-- output: 07/05/2011
```

Otherwise, if you're using sql 2008, you can just cast the datetime to date:

```
select cast(getdate() as date)
```

Comment: I have to compare the times in my WHERE clause so I think I have to keep them as timestamps. Is there another way to do this in 2005?

Comment: You could cast back to datetime via `select cast(convert(varchar, getdate(), 101) as datetime)` but I'm not sure how that would perform versus a datediff solution. What are you really getting at, though? Do you really only need this to query against a particular day? If that's the case, let me know because there's a better way.

Comment: I have two dates I am selecting, and I use a WHERE to determine which row has Date greater than another Date. Both dates have to be converted as m/d/y.

Answer (score 3):

To remove the time you just need to do the following Assuming SQL Server

Pre SQL 2008

```
select DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0) yourdate
FROM yourtable
```

SQL 2008

```
select CAST(getdate() as date) yourdate
FROM yourtable
```

See [Most efficient way in SQL Server to get date from date+time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133081/most-efficient-way-in-sql-server-to-get-date-from-datetime)
or

[Best approach to remove time part of datetime in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server)

Comment: conrad...any trick as to how you get the Q so quickly? 3 mins and with the answer as well...nice!

Comment: @Ram. This just happens to be one of the problems that I face regularly so I have the syntax handy. The links took a little longer but I added them within the first five minutes so you don't get to see the edits.