# How to get Time from DateTime format in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I want to get only Time from DateTime column using SQL query 
using SQL Server 2005 and 2008
Default output:

```
AttDate                   
==
2011-02-09 13:09:00    
2011-02-09 14:10:00
```

I'd like this output:

```
AttDate                Time 
==
2011-02-09 13:09:00    13:09
2011-02-09 14:10:00    14:10
```

Comment: search for to_char method in sql. you can specify the format and get the desired output

Comment: select convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 108)

Comment: It could be `SELECT
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108)` for sql server

Answer (score 438, accepted):

SQL Server 2008:

```
SELECT cast(AttDate as time) [time]
FROM yourtable
```

Earlier versions:

```
SELECT convert(char(5), AttDate, 108) [time]
FROM yourtable
```

Answer (score 49):

Assuming Sql server

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108)
```

Comment: It works only on getdate() where as when I pass select convert(varchar(8),'2011-02-09 13:09:00',108) it is producing the first 8 characters from the date .how to fix this ?

Answer (score 38):

SQL Server 2008+ has a "time" datatype

```
SELECT 
    ..., CAST(MyDateTimeCol AS time)
FROM
   ...
```

For older versions, *without* varchar conversions

```
SELECT 
    ..., DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, MyDateTimeCol, 0), MyDateTimeCol)
FROM
   ...
```

Comment: why you not use this SELECT
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108) AS HourMinuteSecond,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),101) AS DateOnly is there any performance issue ?

Comment: @rahularyansharma: I don't use varchar conversion for dates if needed

Comment: sir i want to know is there any performance decrease if we use this instead of your solution ?

Comment: @rahularyansharma: you can test yourself based on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133081/most-efficient-way-in-sql-server-to-get-date-from-datetime

Comment: For anyone not following, `0` represents the min date `1900-01-01`. So this gets the (negative) number of days between the column value and 0, then adds those negative days to the column value which "zeros out" the date portion to `1900-01-01` and you're left with only the time.

Answer (score 22):

The simplest way to get the time from datetime without millisecond stack is:

```
SELECT convert(time(0),getDate())
```

Answer (score 11):

Try using this

- Date to Time

  ```
  select cast(getdate() as time(0))
  ```
- Time to TinyTime

  ```
  select cast(orig_time as time(0))
  ```

Answer (score 6):

Try this, it will work:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATETIME,114)
```

For your [reference](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-sql-server/to_char_datetime).

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
select  convert(nvarchar,CAST(getdate()as time),100)
```

Answer (score 4):

Get date of server

```
SELECT LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 100), 7)) FROM TABLENAME WHERE ...
```

or

If it is stored in the table

```
SELECT LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), datename, 100), 7)) FROM TABLENAME WHERE ...
```

Result:

> 11:41AM

Answer (score 3):

`select AttDate,convert(char(5), AttDate, 108) [Time] from yourTableName`

Answer (score 3):

```
Declare @date Datetime = '06/18/2021 14:24:31';
Select FORMAT(@date, 'h\:m tt', 'en-US') As Timey
```

***Output:***

```
2:24pm
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

If you want date something in this style: Oct 23 2013 10:30AM

Use this

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30),getdate(), 100)
```

`convert()` method takes 3 parameters

1. datatype
2. Column/Value
3. Style: Available styles are from 100 to 114. You can choose within range from. Choose one by one to change the date format.

Answer (score 2):

I often use this script to get Time from DateTime:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(9),RIGHT(YOURCOLUMN_DATETIME,9),108) FROM YOURTABLE
```

Comment: why do i Get 9 in front of the Time.. 
Result :  9 11:21PM

Answer (score 2):

To get the time from datetime, we can use

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 114)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select cast (as time(0))
```

would be a good clause. For example:

```
(select cast(start_date as time(0))) AS 'START TIME'
```

Answer (score 1):

on MSSQL2012 or above

```
cast(dateadd(ms,datediff(ms, [StartDateTime], [StopDateTime]),0) as Time(0))
```

...or...

```
convert(time(0),dateadd(ms,datediff(ms, [StartDateTime], [StopDateTime]),0) )
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2012:

```
Select TRY_CONVERT(TIME, myDateTimeColumn) from myTable;
```

Personally, I prefer TRY_CONVERT() to CONVERT(). The main difference: If cast fails, TRY_CONVERT() returns NULL while CONVERT() raises an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(),8)
```

Output:

```
08:24
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select convert(char(5), tbl_CustomerBooking.CheckInTime, 108) AS [time]
from tbl_CustomerBooking
```

Answer (score 0):

FORMAT(GETDATE(),'hh:mm tt') AS Time

Output: 09:37 AM

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

`select substr(to_char(colUmn_name, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH:MM:SS'),11,19) from table_name;`

Output: from

```
05:11:26
05:11:24
05:11:24
```

Comment: Does not work gives error `'to_char' is not a recognized built-in function name.`