# Extract time from datetime efficiently (as decimal or datetime)

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2000

I have been able to find a lot of information for getting a string representation of just the time from a datetime column like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7710495/1062992).

I need to get the time part out of a datetime in a way that I can do some math on it like adding it to another datetime. So a string representation of the time wont help me.

However I've only found one [example](http://arjunachith.blogspot.com/2008/01/getting-time-part-only-from-sql.html) that will extract the time as a numeric type value. I.e:

```
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT) - FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT))
```

This method requires *two* casts though and I have to run this on over 10,000 rows. Is there anything similar to the `dateadd` method for extracting the date part from a datetime column i.e.:

```
select DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

that I can use to get just the time out of a datetime column and return it as a decimal or datetime? Perhaps a solution that uses less casting?

I am using SQL Server 2000.

Comment: What is the purpose for your conversion?

Comment: I have to add a time value for an event to a date-only value so that I can compare it with another table as part of a join. The time value for the type of an event I have to extract from another table that holds both dates and times for an event type.

Comment: When you say "numeric value" please note that this would have to be a count of milliseconds, minutes, or other time value, *not* float or decimal, because those don't work! Try `SELECT Convert(datetime, Convert(decimal(38, 31), Convert(datetime, '2012-08-17 00:00:00.003')))`. This yields `2012-08-17 00:00:00.000`. Oops. `float` has the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a `datetime`:

```
SELECT GetDate() - DateDiff(day, 0, GetDate());
-- returns the time with zero as the datetime part (1900-01-01).
```

And to get a number representing the time:

```
SELECT DateDiff(millisecond, DateDiff(day, 0, GetDate()), GetDate());
-- time since midnight in milliseconds, use as you wish
```

If you really want a string, then:

```
SELECT Convert(varchar(8), GetDate(), 108); -- 'hh:mm:ss'
SELECT Convert(varchar(12), GetDate(), 114); -- 'hh:mm:ss.nnn' where nnn is milliseconds
```

Comment: That first one seems like the simplest.

Comment: Needed decimal or datetime because I have to do some more processing in the SQL with the result. The first one does the trick.

Comment: Don't use `decimal`!!! It won't work! Try `SELECT Convert(datetime, Convert(decimal(38, 31), Convert(datetime, '2012-08-17 00:00:00.003')))`. This yields `2012-08-17 00:00:00.000`. Oops. `float` has the same problem.

Comment: Well the first one still works because it's a datetime right? I assume I can add the result of that to another datetime safely?

Answer (score 1):

One way You can get the time in seconds is with:

```
select cast(datediff(second, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0), getdate())/(60*60*24.0) as datetime)
```

This calculates the time in seconds and then converts back to a datetime.

To get it as a decimal:

```
select datediff(second, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0), getdate())/(60*60*24.0)
```

Or use "ms" if you prefer millisecond precision.

Or, you can use the more readable:

```
select datepart(hh, getdate())/24.0+datepart(mm, getdate())/(24*60.0)+
       datepart(ss, getdate())/(24*60*60.0)
```

Comment: That looks workable, any idea if it processes any faster than two casts with all the additional math? I am not very savvy with SQL processing speeds.

Comment: For just 10,000 records, I wouldn't worry about it.  If you were dealing with 50 casts per row and millions of rows, then you might start to nice the performance.  The casts are possibly faster.