# Select time from datetime in SQL Compact

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

Much like this question: "[How to get Time from DateTime format in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710449/how-to-get-time-from-datetime-format-in-sql)", I am trying to select *only* the time from a datetime, but unlike the above question,  I would like to know how to do it in `SQL Server Compact`. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. Luigi's answer is not actually the *correct* one but I have upvoted it, as it helped me find the answer.

To get only the time from a datetime in `SQL Server Compact`, the proper query is:

`select ltrim(str(DATEPART(hour, columnName))) + ':' + ltrim(str(DATEPART(minute, columnName))) + ':' + ltrim(str(DATEPART(second, columnName))) from table`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATEPART(hour, OrderDate), DATEPART(minute, OrderDate) FROM MyOrders
```

Ref. http://msdn.microsoft.com//library/ms173998%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: This isn't working quite how I want. When I use the query `select top(1) DATEPART(hour, DateAdded) + DATEPART(minute, DateAdded), DateAdded from table`, the top result is `38, 02/04/2013 10:28:47`. Not sure how the 38 relates to that date?

Comment: Ah, just worked it out. It has literally added the two numbers together, instead of concatenating them.

Comment: Edited. There was an error because + operator sum 2 return datepart (return an integer)