# SQL Server Compact 4.0 DateTimePicker select query between dates

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview

Using Winforms, .Net 4.5.

I have a form with a DataGridView and in the dataGridView I insert a few values from another form like Client name and Date, I struggled for a few hours to figure it out, I'm using SQL Server Compact 4.0 so it only supports `DateTime` datatype unlike SQL Server 2008 or so where you can store date without time, so what I need to do is some select between dates query.

But in SQL Server Compact you can store only the whole value of date like `24/02/2014 12:00` I only need the date and SQL Server Compact won't let me do that. I tried using `DateTimePicker.Text` to send data to SQL Server Compact but with strings you cannot do a select between dates because they are not dates they are strings. What can I do from this situation, remember I need only date format I don't need the time, remember also SQL Server Compact cannot store only dates. So is there any possible ways to do this select between strings (`dateTimePicker.Text`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store `DateTime` in your database - you really have no other choice.

If you don't need time - use only Date portion of DateTime when performing selects.

**Edited:**

I'm not sure how you do your selects, but if it is just text query then

WHERE clause would look like this:

```
"DateColumn >= '" + sd.ToShortDateString() + "' AND DateColumn <= '" + ed.ToShortDateString() + "'";
```

where *sd* is a start date and *ed* is the end date, both of type DateTime in C#, and *DateColumn* is the column where you keep your dates.
Same idea applies for inserts.

SELECT would look like this (returns 12/12/2013):

```
select ltrim(str(DATEPART(month, DateColumn))) + ':' + ltrim(str(DATEPART(day, DateColumn))) + ':' + ltrim(str(DATEPART(year, DateColumn))) AS MyDate FROM TableName
```

Generic use of DATEPART:

```
SELECT DATEPART(month, [DateColumn]) AS Month FROM TableName
```

More on DATEPART is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173998.aspx)

Also, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760696/select-time-from-datetime-in-sql-compact) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710449/how-to-get-time-from-datetime-format-in-sql)

Comment: Yes it seems I don't, how to select only Date portion of DateTime when performing selects, to be honest Is first time using DateTime data types