# How do I update a record where time > '13:00:00.0'

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

```
UPDATE TimeRecord 
SET activityid = 151
WHERE timevalue >= '13:00:00.0'
```

When I run the query it updates every record instead of the ones greater than the specified timevalue

The timevalue column is formatted as follows

```
2012-05-24 13:00:00.0
```

Comment: Do you want all dates where time >13 or just current date?  Also, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7710495/1618257

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name based on syntax it's `not IN ('oracle', 'postgres', 'ms-access')` could be `in ('MySQL', 'Sql Server' )` not sure about others

Comment: @ConradFrix: could be Postgres as well.

Comment: I am using MSSQL (Express 2012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a date specified, you default to `January, 01 1900 13:00:00`, so you're asking to update any value where `timevalue` is after that date, which is quite likely all of them.

You probably want to use:

```
UPDATE TimeRecord 
SET activityid = 151
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, timevalue) > 13;
```

Comment: Likewise, WHERE CAST(timevalue AS TIME) >= '13:00:00.0'