# SQL time format

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Im making a simple table in sql where i need to specify certain times.
I use datatype time. 
I enter time like this: 5:38
It results in this: 05:38:00.0000000

How do I get rid of all the zeros? Do I have to change data-type?

Comment: Why do you care about how the time is formatted in the DB?

Comment: Which `DBMS` are you using?

Comment: Well, I just thinks it looks pretty bad in my "timetable"..Im just trying to learn SQL som im probably missing something..

Comment: Microsoft management studio

Comment: which sql? MS SQL or MySQL? Even then its the way database stores the time. Just format it when you make a selection.

Comment: You can't change the way a data type is stored in the DB. You can only change the way it is represented to you in your select queries.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710449/how-to-get-time-from-datetime-format-in-sql

Comment: As juergen's comment points to, you need to get used to the being a difference between the information stored and how it's represented.  Internally, date/time/timestamps type are usually some sort of incrementing counter - this makes comparisons **really fast** (because they compare the internal value).  Types like `Decimal` in C# are usually multiple integral variables, but are given a decimal point only on string output.  You should be able to hide the representation in your db client for basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the comments from other users. Possible solutions are:

1. Create a `time(0)` (see the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8d908/7))
2. Use a `convert` to convert the results to your desired **representation** (also in sqlfiddle).

Sample:

```
select convert(char(5), t, 108)
from   tableName
```