# Convert to HH:MM in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to convert a date time format to `hh:mm` using SQL Server.

For example: convert this value `2017-08-17 15:31:18.217` into `15:31`.

If anyone knows how to do this, please help.

Comment: You can convert it to datetime or just use `SELECT SUBSTRING('2017-08-17 15:31:18.217',12,5)`

Comment: If your value is stored as datetime, then this question is duplicate of [How to get Time from DateTime format in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710449/how-to-get-time-from-datetime-format-in-sql)

Comment: Thanks its working..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
DECLARE @DateTime datetime = '2017-08-17 15:31:18.217'

SELECT CONVERT(char(5), @DateTime, 108)
```

Result: `15:31`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT FORMAT(cast('2017-08-17 15:31:18.217' as datetime),'hh:mm')
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Please execute these 2 queries , you will get the hours and minutes of current time.

```
 SELECT GETDATE() 
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME))
```

Comment: @Loki , Please execute these 2 queries , you will get the hours and minutes of current time. That's the requirement.
SELECT GETDATE()
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME))

Comment: Please edit this to the answer. Thus, future users can understand. Also, have a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Loki , Done, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 108)
```

You may want to use `TRY_CONVERT` if supported,and you don't always have a in that column.

One thing, the value that gets converted needs to be of type `DATETIME`.