# Datetiime column needs to show only the time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a datetime column that has data as this:

```
Appt_DateTime  (datetime, not null)`
12/30/1899   7:50:00PM
```

I want to display only the time in this case the 7:50:pm. it can be with or without the seconds, better without them.

How can I do this in a select?

Comment: This was answered in:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710449/how-to-get-time-from-datetime-format-in-sql

Comment: search for convert function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this by using something like

```
Select   cast(<your column name> as time) [time] from <your table>
```