# How to set a substring from a sql statement through Groovy setter

Tags: sql, groovy

I am reading a sql table through a Sql statement, meanwhile i am also using a substring. Since the Substring is like virtual i am not writing in the database. How am i able to set this read substring using a setter in groovy using sql.eachrow.

I have tried `setFinishingTime(row.FinishingTime)`

This is in my groovy code.

```
sql.eachRow('select * from [Database].[dbo].[table] order by FinishingTime')
{ row ->
    ---
    machine.setFinishingTime(row.FinishingTime)
}
```

In sql query i have a code.

```
substring([FinishingTime], charindex(' ', [FinishingTime]) + 1, len([FinishingTime])).
```

I want to set in FinishingTime the substring of the column finishingtime. How can i achieve that, It works in sql management studio but how do i use the same in groovy through sql.eachRow.

Comment: can you post sample record of a row with data ?

Comment: can't understand the problem....

Comment: 15.02.2019 09:08:44 I need just the 09:08:44 for an example. So i use the substring. How can i use this substring result in assigning into eachrow.

Comment: You should tag your question with the underlying database. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710449/how-to-get-time-from-datetime-format-in-sql