# Order by time part only

Tags: sql-server

When I select time in SQL it is returned as  2011-02-25 21:17:33.933. But I need only the time part. How can I do this?  I'm trying to: order by "Onlie Duration" DESc , but need it to be ordered by time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Time from DateTime format in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710449/how-to-get-time-from-datetime-format-in-sql)

Comment: So you don't care about the date portion? So a date of '2019-01-01 09:00:00' would be sorted before '2015-01-01 09:01:00'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT time_column FROM dbo.table 
ORDER BY CONVERT(time, time_column)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Convert function

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
ORDER BY CONVERT(varchar(10), TimeField, 108)
```

**UPD** Or using DATEDIFF:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, CAST(TimeField AS DATE), TimeField)
```

Comment: Not sure that varchar is the best idea...would work with time but not a good habit to sort datetime type of data as characters.

Comment: using DATEDIFF is probably the best way of doing it without any conversion. See Updated portion.

Answer (score 0):

You can get only the time part using:

```
select convert(char,[YourDateColumn],108) from [YourTable]
```

Sorting your data based on time can be done by ordering using:

```
select * from [YourTable] order by convert(char,[yourDateColumn],108)
```

The downside to this is that, sorting with just the time when there are dates for different days will mix the time for the various days.