# Separate Date from DateTime stamp then display by date totals

Tags: sql-server

I am very new to SQL, well rather, I have not used it in 8 years or so. This is being done in a restaurant point-of-sale system that uses SQL Server. Anyhow, here is my current code:

```
select cashier_id,grand_total, num_people_party, datetime
from invoice_totals
where datetime >= '2012-06-01'
```

Ultimately I want to display a report that lists the total number of people served (`num_people_served`) and the grand total (`grand_total`) by the cashier id (`cashier_id`) for each date.

So:

```
Cashier ID 223
2012-06-01   10   200.00
2012-06-02   23   245.00

Cashier ID 224
2012-06-01   15   123.00
2012-06-02   24   254.00

etc...
```

This should not be too tough, but I just don't remember and my searches have not proven useful.  Also, it should be noted that the `DateTime` field will need to be split in order to group the totals by date.

---

In adding the dividion field from the comment below, I get the following error once it is added:

```
Message: Could not retrieve datatable.
SELECT CASHIER_ID AS SERVER, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[DATETIME],111) AS DATE, SUM(GRAND_TOTAL) AS TOTAL_SALES, SUM(NUM_PEOPLE_PARTY) AS NUMBER_SERVED, SUM(GRAND_TOTAL) / SUM(NUM_PEOPLE_PARTY) AS CASHPERCUSTOMER
FROM INVOICE_TOTALS
WHERE [DATETIME] >= '2012-06-01'
GROUP BY CASHIER_ID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[DATETIME],111) 
Stack Trace:    at PCA_DataMod.PCA_DB.OpenDT(String SQLLoadInfo, Boolean NoSchema)
   at PCA_DataMod.PCA_DB.OpenDT(String SQLLoadInfo)
   at pcAmerica.Desktop.POS.Forms.frmReportCustomWiz.GetRawSQLFields()
   at pcAmerica.Desktop.POS.Forms.frmReportCustomWiz.Display_Step(WizardStep Index)

Message: Divide by zero error encountered.
Stack Trace:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.HasMoreRows()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillLoadDataRow(SchemaMapping mapping)
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
   at PCA_DataMod.PCA_DB.OpenDT(String SQLLoadInfo, Boolean NoSchema)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most efficient way in SQL Server to get date from date+time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133081/most-efficient-way-in-sql-server-to-get-date-from-datetime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `group by` the cashier and the day:

```
select     cashier_id
,          dateadd(d, 0, datediff(d, 0, [datetime]))
,          sum(grand_total)
,          sum(num_people_party)
from       invoice_totals
where      [datetime] >= '2012-06-01'
group by
           cashier_id
,          dateadd(d, 0, datediff(d, 0, [datetime]))
```

In SQL Server 2008 and later, you can replace

```
dateadd(d, 0, datediff(d, 0, [datetime]))
```

with

```
cast([datetime] as date)
```

Comment: This seems to work great, a couple of follow-ups:  
-How can I change the name of the columns on the report, it current shows as CASHIER_ID, column 1, column 2, column 3?
-Is there a way to omit the time from showing, it currently shows the dates and then a time of 12:00:00 AM for each record?
-How Could I add 1 more column that divides the grand total by the number of people served for each record?

Comment: 1, Add `as Alias` at the end, like `sum(grand_total) as total`.  2. Replace `dateadd(d, 0, datediff(d, 0, [datetime]))` with `convert(varchar(10),[datetime],111)`  3. `sum(grand_total) / sum(num_people_party) as CashPerCustomer`

Comment: 2 of 3 of those work perfectly!  However, the division line seems to throw an error.  I updated my original question to show the error message that is thrown.  I really appreciate your help with this!

Comment: There was a divide by zero error, I added a case statement to take care of it.  Thanks again for your help, I appreciate you taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

You can group by the date parts:

```
select cashier_id,SUM(grand_total), SUM(num_people_party), DATEPART(dd,[datetime]) AS Day, DATEPART(mm,[datetime]) AS Month, DATEPART(yyyy,[datetime]) AS Year
from invoice_totals
where datetime >= '2012-06-01'
group by cashier_id, DATEPART(dd,[datetime]), DATEPART(mm,[datetime]), DATEPART(yyyy,[datetime])
```

Or more simply

```
select cashier_id, SUM(grand_total), SUM(num_people_party), DAY([datetime]) AS Day, MONTH([datetime]) AS Month, YEAR([datetime]) AS Year
from invoice_totals
where datetime >= '2012-06-01'
group by cashier_id, DAY([datetime]), MONTH([datetime]), YEAR([datetime])
```