# how to get today's Date only and not with the time using sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Most efficient way in SQL Server to get date from date+time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133081/most-efficient-way-in-sql-server-to-get-date-from-datetime)

I want to update a field with today's date only but the problem i am having now is it is giving me the date and the time.  I would like to update with specific format like this:
11/09/2012
how can i achieve this?  here is my current code:

```
UPDATE MyTable  
        SET Field1 = GETDATE()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server

Comment: FYI, to get it as the format you want, the answer is : `Select Convert( Varchar(10), GetDate(), 101 )`. Beware, the data type is `varchar`. You cannot force the format to MM/DD/YYYY unless it is varchar.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way is to update and select only date (not time)

```
 UPDATE @tab SET dates=(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),103));
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 23) FROM @tab
```

Answer (score 4):

Not much different here apart from slight syntax differences however I would recommend wrapping it up in a function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDateOnly] (@Datetime datetime) 

RETURNS datetime  

AS  

BEGIN  
    RETURN CONVERT(Datetime, FLOOR(CONVERT(float,@Datetime)))  
END
```