# Datetime function to get specific dates 12:00AM time

Tags: sql-server, formatting, datetime-format

if any date time value provided to sql server can i get it's midnight value with some function in sql server.. for example if i provide 2013/07/03 01:34AM , i want to get it to 2013/07/03 12:00 AM.Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server 2008+

```
SELECT CAST(CAST('2013/07/03 01:34AM' AS date) AS datetime)
```

For older versions, see this [Best approach to remove time part of datetime in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server/1177529#1177529) Never use anything that requires float or int or varchar conversions

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you need:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, InputDateField), 0)
```

Should be slightly quicker than cast:
[Most efficient way in SQL Server to get date from date+time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133081/most-efficient-way-in-sql-server-to-get-date-from-datetime)