# How can I truncate a datetime in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, truncate

What's the best way to truncate a datetime value (as to remove hours minutes and seconds) in SQL Server?

For example:

```
declare @SomeDate datetime = '2009-05-28 16:30:22'
select trunc_date(@SomeDate)

-----------------------
2009-05-28 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 564, accepted):

This continues to frequently gather additional votes, even several years later, and so I need to update it for modern versions of Sql Server. For Sql Server 2008 and later, it's simple:

```sql
cast(getdate() as Date)
```

Note that the last three paragraphs near the bottom still apply, and you often need to take a step back and find a way to avoid the cast in the first place.

But there are other ways to accomplish this, too. Here are the most common.

#### The correct way (new since Sql Server 2008)

```sql
cast(getdate() as Date)
```

#### The correct way (old)

```sql
dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

This is older now, but it's still worth knowing because it can also easily adapt for other time points, like the first moment of the month, minute, hour, or year.

This correct way uses documented functions that are part of the ANSI standard and are guaranteed to work, but it can be somewhat slower. It works by finding how many days there are from day 0 to the current day, and adding that many days back to day 0. It will work no matter how your `datetime` is stored and no matter what your locale is.

#### The fast way

```sql
cast(floor(cast(getdate() as float)) as datetime)
```

This works because `datetime` columns are stored as 8-byte binary values. Cast them to `float`, `floor` them to remove the fraction, and the time portion of the values are gone when you cast them back to `datetime`. It's all just bit shifting with no complicated logic and it's *very* fast.

Be aware this relies on an implementation detail that Microsoft is free to change at any time, even in an automatic service update. It's also not very portable. In practice, it's very unlikely this implementation will change any time soon, but it's still important to be aware of the danger if you choose to use it. And now that we have the option to cast as a date, it's rarely necessary.

#### The wrong way

```sql
cast(convert(char(11), getdate(), 113) as datetime)
```

The wrong way works by converting to a string, truncating the string, and converting back to a datetime. It's *wrong,* for two reasons:

1. It might not work across all locales and
2. It's about the slowest possible way to do this...  and not just a little; it's like an order of magnitude or two slower than the other options.

---

**Update** This has been getting some votes lately, and so I want to add to it that since I posted this I've seen some pretty solid evidence that Sql Server will optimize away the performance difference between "correct" way and the "fast" way, meaning you should now favor the former.

In either case, you want to **write your queries to avoid the need to do this in the first place.**  It's very rare that you should do this work on the database.

In most places, the database is already your bottleneck.  It's generally the server that's the most expensive to add hardware to for performance improvements and the hardest one to get those additions right (you have to balance disks with memory, for example).  It's also the hardest to scale outward, both technically and from a business standpoint; it's much easier technically to add a web or application server than a database server and even if that were false you don't pay $20,000+ per server license for IIS or Apache.

The point I'm trying to make is that whenever possible you should do this work at the application level.  The *only* time you should ever find yourself truncating a `datetime` on Sql Server is when you need to group by the day, and even then you should probably have an extra column set up as a computed column, maintained at insert/update time, or maintained in application logic. Get this index-breaking, CPU-heavy work off your database.

Comment: Joel, your update to this post is useful. What's strange is that I found the DateDiff method to be faster, at least in SQL 2008. I'll try running my tests in SQL 2000 and will see if I can post an update.

Comment: the "fast way" is still the fastest way for sql 2008 according to a benchmark I just ran

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1177449/27535 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/133081/27535 The dateadd/datediff "wins...". For a single variable, who cares of course, and one hopes that you have computed columns or such over a million rows :-)

Comment: This "correct" way only accidentally works.  The way it is written is as if the syntax for DateAdd were (interval, date, increment), but it isn't.  It is (interval, increment, date).  I stumbled on this when I tried to truncate a date to the first of the month:  SELECT DATEADD( m, 0, DATEDIFF( m, 0, GETDATE( ) ) ) does not work, but SELECT DATEADD( m, DATEDIFF( m, 0, GETDATE( ) ), 0  ) does.  At least, this is what I see in 2008R2.

Comment: @Kelly in 2008R2, why not just `cast(getdate() as date)`?

Comment: I ran into substantial performance degradation when using the `CAST` method in SQL Server 2008 R2. I was using it in a query that covered ~8.5m rows, and it took at least half an hour (before I terminating the query). Removing the `CAST` method and using the "old correct way" made the query instant.

Comment: 'The fast way' work on datetime column as well and not just on `getdate()` function. For example: This `CAST(FLOOR(CAST(CreatedDate AS float)) AS datetime) AS CreatedDate` work.., where `CreatedDate` is a column in your table.

Comment: They _all_ work on a datetime column. `getdate()` here is a stand-in for whatever datetime source you may have.

Comment: Re: `Get this cpu-heavy work off your database.`  Is it really THAT much work though? I mean my *telephone* can render a very complex 3D environment with millions of texture mapped triangles 60 times a second. Is removing the time from a date in SQL Server really going to cause a problem you could even measure (even for millions of rows)?

Comment: Regarding my above comment: I just did some tests. All four methods take exactly the same amount of time to run to within 2%. I tested on a million iterations and it took 3300ms in each instance, to within 20ms. Even the "slow" way is just as fast as the other methods (SQL Server 2012). Removing the cast completely as a control saves about 30% (ie, SQL Server seems to spend 2 seconds in 1M iterations of an empty while loop - which surprised me!).

Comment: Your telephone is only serving one user. Your DB needs to handle potentially thousands of users simultaneously, with each user running several queries and each query needing potentially thousands to millions of calculations. Yes, that CPU difference can definitely matter.  For the testing... these things can change version to version, but you also need to be very sure you're running fair tests. Sql Server does a lot of things with caching, indexing, etc that can invalidate simple tests.

Comment: A couple of notes: 1) DateDiff/DateAdd from zero can also be used to at other time intervals besides day, `DATEADD(MONTH, datediff(MONTH,0, GETDATE()), 0)`. 2) The fast way `cast to float -> floor -> cast to datetime` does not work for datetime2 unless additional casts to/from datetime are added.

Comment: I like your solution "the correct way (old)" because it works in many many other usecases.

Answer (score 45):

For SQL Server 2008 only

```
CAST(@SomeDateTime AS Date)
```

Then cast it back to datetime if you want

```
CAST(CAST(@SomeDateTime AS Date) As datetime)
```

Comment: Good point: I'm still on 2005 and so for 2008 this is probably the new "correct" way and may even match the performance of the "fast" way.

Comment: The performance of this new way is even faster than the "fast" way.

Answer (score 27):

Just for the sake of a more complete answer, here's a working way for truncating to any of the date parts down and including minutes (replace `GETDATE()` with the date to truncate).

This is different from the accepted answer in that you can use not only `dd` (days), but any of the date parts (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)):

```
dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Note that in the expression above, the `0` is a constant date on the beginning of a year (1900-01-01). If you need to truncate to smaller parts, such as to seconds or milliseconds, you need to take a constant date which is closer to the date to be truncated to avoid an overflow.

Comment: This was monstrously helpful. I looked all over for a way to truncate the date-time at a place lower than the full day.

Comment: Just so the internet knows, you don't have to be restricted to full datepart periods. Here's an example for 15 minute intervals, using integer division: `dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, GETDATE()) / 15 * 15, 0)`

Answer (score 7):

The snippet I found on the web when I had to do this was:

```
 dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0, YOURDATE))
 e.g.
 dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0, getDate()))
```

Comment: I'm on 2005, but I thought 2008 had some new function for this??

Comment: Neat! I would have resorted to splitting out the dateparts and using string handling to putting them back together. 
May not be relevant, but SQL2008 has a pure date-only data type without a time element.

Comment: And note you have the DateAdd operands mixed up, it's `DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(...), 0)`. This can bite you if you're not careful.

Answer (score 3):

```
CONVERT(DATE, <yourdatetime>) or CONVERT(DATE, GetDate()) or CONVERT(DATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Answer (score 2):

When working with analytics you probably need date\time truncation a lot. So I made a small function to help sorting this out:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TRUNC_DATE
(
    @datetime datetime, -- datetime to be truncated
    @level VARCHAR(10)  -- truncation level: year, month, day, hour and minute
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN

    IF (UPPER(@level) = 'YEAR')
       RETURN DATEADD(YEAR,   DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, @datetime), 0)
    ELSE IF (UPPER(@level) = 'MONTH')
        RETURN DATEADD(MONTH,   DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @datetime), 0)
    ELSE IF(UPPER(@level) = 'DAY')
       RETURN DATEADD(DAY,   DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @datetime), 0)
    ELSE IF (UPPER(@level) = 'HOUR')
       RETURN DATEADD(HOUR,   DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, @datetime), 0)
    ELSE IF (UPPER(@level) = 'MINUTE')
       RETURN DATEADD(MINUTE,   DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, @datetime), 0)

    RETURN @datetime
END
GO
```

To evalute the function (change the GETDATE() with you column):

```
SELECT DBO.TRUNC_DATE(GETDATE(), 'YEAR')   YEAR;
SELECT DBO.TRUNC_DATE(GETDATE(), 'MONTH')  YEAR_MONTH;
SELECT DBO.TRUNC_DATE(GETDATE(), 'DAY')    YEAR_MONTH_DAY;
SELECT DBO.TRUNC_DATE(GETDATE(), 'HOUR')   YEAR_MONTH_DAY_HOUR;
SELECT DBO.TRUNC_DATE(GETDATE(), 'MINUTE') YEAR_MONTH_DAY_HOUR_MINUTE;
```

The output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In SQL 2005, your `trunc_date` function could be written like this.

1. The first method is much much cleaner. It uses only 3 method calls including the final `CAST()` and performs no string concatenation, which is an automatic plus. Furthermore, there are no huge type casts here. If you can imagine that Date/Time stamps can be represented, then converting from dates to numbers and back to dates is a fairly easy process.

   ```sql
   CREATE FUNCTION trunc_date(@date DATETIME)
   RETURNS DATETIME
   AS
   BEGIN
       CAST(FLOOR( CAST( @date AS FLOAT ) )AS DATETIME)
   END
   ```
2. If you are concerned about Microsoft's implementation of `DATETIME`s, (2) or (3) might be okay.

   ```sql
   CREATE FUNCTION trunc_date(@date DATETIME)
   RETURNS DATETIME
   AS
   BEGIN
         SELECT CONVERT(varchar, @date,112)
   END
   ```
3. Third, the more verbose method. This requires breaking the date into its year, month, and day parts, putting them together in "yyyy/mm/dd" format, then casting that back to a date. This method involves 7 method calls including the final `CAST()`, not to mention string concatenation.

   ```sql
   CREATE FUNCTION trunc_date(@date DATETIME)
   RETURNS DATETIME
   AS
   BEGIN
   SELECT CAST((STR( YEAR( @date ) ) + '/' +STR( MONTH( @date ) ) + '/' +STR( DAY(@date ) )
   ) AS DATETIME
   END
   ```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2022 have DATETRUNC

```
DECLARE @d datetime2 = '2021-12-08 11:30:15.1234567';
SELECT 'Year', DATETRUNC(year, @d);
SELECT 'Quarter', DATETRUNC(quarter, @d);
SELECT 'Month', DATETRUNC(month, @d);
SELECT 'Week', DATETRUNC(week, @d); -- Using the default DATEFIRST setting value of 7 (U.S. English)
SELECT 'Iso_week', DATETRUNC(iso_week, @d);
SELECT 'DayOfYear', DATETRUNC(dayofyear, @d);
SELECT 'Day', DATETRUNC(day, @d);
SELECT 'Hour', DATETRUNC(hour, @d);
SELECT 'Minute', DATETRUNC(minute, @d);
SELECT 'Second', DATETRUNC(second, @d);
SELECT 'Millisecond', DATETRUNC(millisecond, @d);
SELECT 'Microsecond', DATETRUNC(microsecond, @d);
```

```
Year        2021-01-01 00:00:00.0000000
Quarter     2021-10-01 00:00:00.0000000
Month       2021-12-01 00:00:00.0000000
Week        2021-12-05 00:00:00.0000000
Iso_week    2021-12-06 00:00:00.0000000
DayOfYear   2021-12-08 00:00:00.0000000
Day         2021-12-08 00:00:00.0000000
Hour        2021-12-08 11:00:00.0000000
Minute      2021-12-08 11:30:00.0000000
Second      2021-12-08 11:30:15.0000000
Millisecond 2021-12-08 11:30:15.1230000
Microsecond 2021-12-08 11:30:15.1234560
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetrunc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: The OP did specifically say 2008 in their request.

Comment: @JeffModen Perhaps, but it's often necessary to update questions with newer functionality esp when older versions become deprecated. You wouldn't expect a question stating C# v2 to remain with only older answers. And this post is pretty much the canonical for this type of question

Comment: @Charlieface - Ah... ok.  I see where you're coming from.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who came here looking for a way to truncate a `DATETIME` field to something less than a whole day, for example every minute, you can use this:

```sql
SELECT CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) + (FLOOR((CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT) - FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT))) * 1440.0) + (3.0/86400000.0)) / 1440.0 AS DATETIME)
```

So if today was `2010-11-26 14:54:43.123` then this would return `2010-11-26 14:54:00.000`.

To change the interval it truncates to, replace 1440.0 with the number of intervals in a day, for example:

| Truncate to | Formula | Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hour | 24 hours/day | 24.0 |
| Half hour | 24 hours/day / 2 | 48.0 |
| Minute | 24 hours/day * 60 minutes/hour | 1440.0 |

(Always put a `.0` on the end to implicitly cast to a float.)

---

For those of you wondering what the `(3.0/86400000)` is for in my calculation, SQL Server 2005 doesn't seem to cast from `FLOAT` to `DATETIME` accurately, so this adds 3 milliseconds before flooring it.

Comment: Be careful with rounding errors due to floating point precision limits though... also, this doesn't work with the `datetime2` data type.

Comment: For Hour, SELECT DATEADD( hour, DATEDIFF( hour, 0, GETDATE( ) ), 0  ) works, also.  Minute, too, but Second will result in an overflow.

Comment: Casting to float and back to datetime [doesn't work correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775/whats-the-best-way-to-remove-the-time-portion-of-a-datetime-value-sql-server/3696991#3696991).

Answer (score 0):

This query should give you result equivalent to `trunc(sysdate)` in Oracle.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    your_table
WHERE   CONVERT(varchar(12), your_column_name, 101)
      = CONVERT(varchar(12), GETDATE(), 101)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can also extract date `using Substring` from the datetime variable and casting back to datetime will ignore time part.

```
declare @SomeDate datetime = '2009-05-28 16:30:22'
SELECT cast(substring(convert(varchar(12),@SomeDate,111),0,12) as Datetime)
```

Also, you can access parts of datetime variable and merge them to a construct truncated date, something like this:

```
SELECT cast(DATENAME(year, @Somedate) + '-' + 
       Convert(varchar(2),DATEPART(month, @Somedate)) + '-' +
       DATENAME(day, @Somedate) 
       as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle:

```
TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH')
```

SQL Server:

```
DATEADD(DAY, - DATEPART(DAY, DateField) + 1, DateField)
```

Could be similarly used for truncating minutes or hours from a date.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `DATE` with SQL 2008:

```sql
declare @SomeDate date = getdate()

select @SomeDate
```

Answer (score -1):

select cast(floor(cast(getdate() as float)) as datetime)
Reference this: http://microsoftmiles.blogspot.com/2006/11/remove-time-from-datetime-in-sql-server.html

Comment: Casting to float and back to datetime [doesn't work correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775/whats-the-best-way-to-remove-the-time-portion-of-a-datetime-value-sql-server/3696991#3696991).