# How to convert datetime to date only (with time set to 00:00:00.000)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a string '2009-06-24 09:52:43.000', which I need to insert to a DateTime column of a table.

But I don't care about the time, just want to insert it as 2009-06-24 00:00:00.000

How can I do that in T-SQL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I truncate a datetime in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923295/how-can-i-truncate-a-datetime-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For SQL Server 2005 and below:

```sql
CONVERT(varchar(8), @ParamDate, 112)    -- Supported way

CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@ParamDate AS float)) AS DATETIME)   -- Unsupported way
```

For SQL Server 2008 and above:

```sql
CAST(@ParamDate AS DATE)
```

For SQL Server 2022 and above:

```sql
DATETRUNC(d, @ParamDate)
```

Comment: I use the "unsupported way" here all the time.  What's with the 112 magic number on the first line?

Comment: It is the format specifier for the date.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Correct. And please note only 112 is correct because it's an ISO format (as opposed to locale-dependant formats).

Comment: why varchar(8) as an input to convert ?

Comment: Saobi: It's destination data type, not input.

Comment: Your supported way dose not leave the data in the correct format that Saobi asked for.  Also your unsupported way uses too many system functions which wastes resources.  Its like using a sledge hammer to drive a screw.

Comment: DBAndrew: Supported way isn't mine, it's Microsoft's. I did not bother with explicit conversion here as Saobi wanted to insert the result into a datetime column in which case that varchar(8) would be implicitly (and properly, what's most important) converted to datetime.
Unsupported way also isn't mine, it's sorta "well known" basing on datetime storage format specs. Despite number of functions used, it's much faster as it doesn't involve any string parsing.

Comment: What he is saying is 112 is yyyymmdd. 121 is  yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm which is what the guy asked for.

Answer (score 14):

```
declare @originalDate datetime
select @originalDate = '2009-06-24 09:52:43.000'

declare @withoutTime datetime
select @withoutTime = dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, @originalDate), 0)

select @withoutTime
```

Comment: This is The cool and elegant solution... but it only works if the input value is in fact a datetime.  If you start with a string (varchar), you'd have to first convert it to a datetime, and doing that with 100% accuracy is one of the biggest headaches in programming.

Answer (score 10):

I have found that casting as a date, then to a datetime to be very efficient and intuitive.

```
 SELECT CAST(CAST(GETDATE() as date) as datetime)
```

Comment: For me this looks like the simplest solution. No parameters or varchar converts. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),102) AS DATETIME)

SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'2009-06-24 09:52:43.000',102) AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 3):

An enhancement to the unsupported version:
I am not sure if this may effect any performance. `getdate()` is an input timestamp in my query.

`select cast(cast(getdate() as DATE) as DATETIME)`

Answer (score 2):

James is correct. If you're starting off with a string, and the format will always be what you say it is, then you keep it simple and efficient. Use `LEFT( @StrDate, 10)` and `CONVERT` that to your datetime value. Done.

If your input string could be *any* valid date/time format, then you have to use `CONVERT(datetime, @StrDate)` first. After that you go with what Bing just said to strip off the time part.

Answer (score 1):

cast it to a date, and then you can use CONVERT to get just the date.

```
INSERT MyTable(Column1)
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(8), CAST('2009-06-24 09:52:43.000' AS DATETIME), 112)
```

Comment: Guys, why do you all use the 101 format? It's locale-dependant, it's only fine under EN-US locale. Under EN-GB it's already not as in the UK it's dd/mm/yyyy, not mm/dd/yyyy. Use the 112, it doesn't depend on anything.

Comment: I agree don't use 101, use 112 aka ISO or 102 ANSI.

Comment: I agree - i generally use 112 for development, but 101 generally looks more readable in the output when running sample code.

Comment: updated answer to use the ISO date to make it more friendly outside of the US.

Answer (score 1):

If you will always have the date in the same format, i.e. yyyy-MM-DD you can grab the first 10 characters if the value and insert that which is the equivelant of 00:00:00.0000 time for that date.

```
select left('2009-12-32 4:32:00',10)
```

This is a very efficient way to do this as it does't require converting data types HOWEVER, it does require that the date will always be formatted with a four digit year and two digit day & month.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a cleaner and more portable way to do this, but my years old idiom is:

```
insert into tbl (date_column)
select convert(varchar, convert (datetime, '2009-06-24 09:52:43.000'), 101)
```

Answer (score 0):

A variety of hacks:

- Convert your string to a datetime, then back again using the optional "style" parameter to `convert` to convert your datetime to a string using just the date portion
- use `substring` to chop off the end
- round the datetime using `floor`

Answer (score 0):

SELECT CAST('07/10/2022 09:00:00' AS DATE)
will give you

before   - '07/10/2022 09:00:00'
after    - '07/10/2022 00:00:00'

Comment: What does that add to the existing answers posted 14 years ago?

Answer (score -2):

Strip the time, and cast it to date:

```
select cast(left(yourstring, 10) as datetime)
```

Comment: This relies on the formatting of time in a date first format.  You cannot assume this to be true in all string datetime formats.