# DATEPART not working like i think it must

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select * 
  from Advertisements 
 where DepartureDate < DATEPART('dd.mm.yy', '09.10.2010');
```

but i get

Msg 1023, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Invalid parameter 1 specified for datepart.

in plsql is this very simple here is so complicated...
Can someone tell me please how can i get all dates that are smaller than today.

Comment: hey, i've got many parts that don't work as i think they must ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to get the current date:

```
CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
```

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx).

> Can someone tell me please how can i get all dates that are smaller than today.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Advertisements 
WHERE DepartureDate < CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
```

Comment: For anyone new to SQL Server 2008, this might look a bit confusing. Possibly worth pointing out that GETDATE() returns a DATETIME datatype. CONVERTing it to DATE truncates the time portion.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) with `FORMAT_DATE` (which does not exist anyway).

`DATEPART` extracts certain part of a date. Exactly one part.

Dates that are smaller than today are `< dbo.CropTime(getdate())`, where CropTime is a function which can be written in different ways (such as those described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040654/how-to-convert-datetime-to-date-only-with-time-set-to-000000-000)).

Or, in case you are using SQL Server 2008, it's as simple as `< cast(getdate() as date)`.

Answer (score 1):

Would that code really work in PL/SQL? The DATEPART in T-SQL function is used to extract individual portions of a date.

This will get you all the dates before now.

```
select * from Advertisements where DepartureDate < getdate()
```

If you're planning to hardcode the date (as your sample code suggests), you just need to format in a way that SQL Server will understand. eg.

```
select * from Advertisements where DepartureDate < '2010-10-09'
```

I've been told that date format works on every server regardless of its localization settings. It's certainly worked on every server I've tried it on - but I'm happy to be overruled :-)

Answer (score 1):

DatePart is used for getting components of the date such as the month, year or day. To get dates that are smaller (older) than now I would do this.

```
select * from Advertisements where DepartureDate < GetDate();
```

If I wanted Departure dates that were yesterday or before I could do this.

```
select * from Advertisements where DepartureDate < Convert(DateTime,Convert(Char(10),GetDate(),121));
```

or

```
select * from Advertisements where DepartureDate < Convert(DateTime,floor(convert(int,GetDate())))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for I think is

```
select * 
from Advertisements 
where DepartureDate < Convert(Date, '09.10.2010', 102)
```

or possibly

```
SELECT *
FROM Advertisements
WHERE DepartureDate < Cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date)
```