# What is the best way to truncate a date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I have a date value like `2010-03-01 17:34:12.018`

What is the most efficient way to turn this into `2010-03-01 00:00:00.000`?

As a secondary question, what is the best way to emulate Oracle's `TRUNC` function, which will allow you to truncate at Year, Quarter, Month, Week, Day, Hour, Minute, and Second boundaries?

Comment: Here is similar question with a nice explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923295/how-to-truncate-a-datetime-in-sql-server

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To round to the nearest **whole day**, there are three approaches in wide use.  The first one uses `datediff` to find the number of days since the `0` datetime.  The `0` datetime corresponds to the 1st of January, 1900.  By adding the day difference to the start date, you've rounded to a whole day;

```
select dateadd(d, 0, datediff(d, 0, getdate()))
```

The second method is text based: it truncates the text description with `varchar(10)`, leaving only the date part:

```
select convert(varchar(10),getdate(),111)
```

The third method uses the fact that a `datetime` is really a floating point representing the number of days since 1900.  So by rounding it to a whole number, for example using `floor`, you get the start of the day:

```
select cast(floor(cast(getdate() as float)) as datetime)
```

To answer your second question, the **start of the week** is trickier.  One way is to subtract the day-of-the-week:

```
select dateadd(dd, 1 - datepart(dw, getdate()), getdate())
```

This returns a time part too, so you'd have to combine it with one of the time-stripping methods to get to the first date.  For example, with `@start_of_day` as a variable for readability:

```
declare @start_of_day datetime
set @start_of_day = cast(floor(cast(getdate() as float)) as datetime)
select dateadd(dd, 1 - datepart(dw, @start_of_day), @start_of_day)
```

The **start of the year, month, hour and minute** still work with the "difference since 1900" approach:

```
select dateadd(yy, datediff(yy, 0, getdate()), 0)
select dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, getdate()), 0)
select dateadd(hh, datediff(hh, 0, getdate()), 0)
select dateadd(mi, datediff(mi, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

**Rounding by second** requires a different approach, since the number of seconds since `0` gives an overflow.  One way around that is using the start of the day, instead of 1900, as a reference date:

```
declare @start_of_day datetime
set @start_of_day = cast(floor(cast(getdate() as float)) as datetime)
select dateadd(s, datediff(s, @start_of_day, getdate()), @start_of_day)
```

To **round by 5 minutes**, adjust the minute rounding method.  Take the quotient of the minute difference, for example using `/5*5`:

```
select dateadd(mi, datediff(mi,0,getdate())/5*5, 0)
```

This works for quarters and half hours as well.

Comment: Which is going to perform the best?

Comment: As far as I know, the performance difference is too small to be measured

Comment: That's what I wanna know too!!! I use the second one in my code, but I was curious if there was a faster way to do it. The first one is two date functions with a third function call, so there's at least three parsing operations, whereas the second is a single cast to string with a format applied (but therein lies the rub, what happens in the libraries?) ...

Comment: The first one runs in a quarter of the time.

Comment: So, my curiosity got the better of me and I ran some tests against SQL 2008 with 1 million datetime rows. All three methods(cast to float, datediff, cast to date) are pretty close in performance. Casting to a float was the fastest followed by casting to a date then the datediff method was "last" (but still fast).

Comment: I just noticed that the float cast method would not work in a datetime2 data-type. So probably choosing this method would make your code not portable if the table is changed to datetime2 in the future.

Answer (score 19):

If you are using SQL Server 2008+, you can use the `Date` datatype like this:

```
select cast(getdate() as date)
```

If you still need your value to be a `DateTime` datatype, you can do this:

```
select cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime)
```

A method that should work on all versions of SQL Server is:

```
select cast(floor(cast(getdate() as float)) as datetime)
```

Comment: I bet this is the fastest, avoiding arithmetic altogether.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

**UPDATE:** answer on the second question:
for years you could use a little bit modified version of my answer:

```
SELECT DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

for quarter:

```
SELECT DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

and so on.

I checked, up to minutes - it's OK. But on seconds I've got an overflow message:

> Difference of two datetime columns
>   caused overflow at runtime.

**One more update:** take a look to the following answer to the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923295/how-to-truncate-a-datetime-in-sql-server/923322#923322)

Answer (score 3):

This is late, but will produce the exact results requested in the post.  I also feel it is much more intuitive than using dateadd, but that is my preference.

```
declare @SomeDate datetime = '2010-03-01 17:34:12.018'
SELECT 
 DATEFROMPARTS(
     YEAR(@SomeDate)
    ,MONTH(@SomeDate)
    ,'01'
    ) AS CUR_DATE_FROM_PARTS
,DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
     YEAR(@SomeDate)                     
    ,MONTH(@SomeDate)                
    ,'01' --DAY(@SomeDate)                   
    ,'00' --DATEPART(HOUR,@SomeDate)         
    ,'00' --DATEPART(MINUTE,@SomeDate)       
    ,'00' --DATEPART(SECOND,@SomeDate)       
    ,'00' --DATEPART(MILLISECOND,@SomeDate) 
    ) AS CUR_DATETIME_FROM_PARTS
,@SomeDate                         AS CUR_DATETIME
,YEAR(@SomeDate)                   AS CUR_YEAR
,MONTH(@SomeDate)                  AS CUR_MONTH
,DAY(@SomeDate)                    AS CUR_DAY
,DATEPART(HOUR,@SomeDate)          AS CUR_HOUR
,DATEPART(MINUTE,@SomeDate)        AS CUR_MINUTE
,DATEPART(SECOND,@SomeDate)        AS CUR_SECOND
,DATEPART(MILLISECOND,@SomeDate)   AS CUR_MILLISECOND
FROM Your_Table
```

Truncated Date: 2010-03-01

Truncated DateTime: 2010-03-01 00:00:00.000

DateTime: 2010-03-01 17:34:12.017

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2022 introduces the [`DATETRUNC()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetrunc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), which is similar to the long-available Oracle `TRUNC()` function. It's also available in Azure SQL.

Syntax: `DATETRUNC(datepart, date)`

```sql
SELECT
  1 AS SortKey,
  '(none)' AS [Trunc date part],
  'Right now' AS Result,
  SYSDATETIME() AS Value
UNION SELECT 2, 'YEAR', 'Beginning of this year', DATETRUNC(YEAR, SYSDATETIME())
UNION SELECT 3, 'MONTH', 'Beginning of this month', DATETRUNC(MONTH, SYSDATETIME())
UNION SELECT 4, 'DAY', 'Zero hour today', DATETRUNC(DAY, SYSDATETIME())
UNION SELECT 5, 'HOUR', 'Beginning of this hour', DATETRUNC(HOUR, SYSDATETIME())
UNION SELECT 6, 'MINUTE', 'Beginning of this minute', DATETRUNC(MINUTE, SYSDATETIME())
UNION SELECT 7, 'SECOND', 'Beginning of this second', DATETRUNC(SECOND, SYSDATETIME())
ORDER BY SortKey
```

Results from running at around 11:30 PM on 16 June 2023:

| SortKey | Trunc date part | Result | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | (none) | Right now | 2023-06-17 03:30:04.4097820 |
| 2 | YEAR | Beginning of this year | 2023-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 3 | MONTH | Beginning of this month | 2023-06-01 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 4 | DAY | Zero hour today | 2023-06-17 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 5 | HOUR | Beginning of this hour | 2023-06-17 03:00:00.0000000 |
| 6 | MINUTE | Beginning of this minute | 2023-06-17 03:30:00.0000000 |
| 7 | SECOND | Beginning of this second | 2023-06-17 03:30:04.0000000 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iNtzL9gX)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most efficient, but I like the simplicity in using the following where @SomeDate is your field.

```
Concat(Year(@SomeDate), '-', Month(@SomeDate), '-', '01')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to truncate a date to the **start of the week** in a way that is independent of `SET DATEFIRST` you can:

```
--change a date backwards to nearest Monday
DATEADD(DAY, (DATEPART(dw, '2001-01-01') - DATEPART(dw, YOUR_COLUMN)-7)%7, YOUR_COLUMN)
```

Breaking this down:

- `DATEPART(dw, '2001-01-01') - DATEPART(dw, YOUR_COLUMN)`: the `dw` of a known Monday (2001-01-01 was a Monday) minus the `dw` of your date, effectively giving the "number of days difference between your date and Monday" or "how many days back do we have to scroll your date to make it into Monday"
- `( ... -7)%7` - we subtract 7 from it and modulo the result by 7.

  - We do this because if e.g. DATEFIRST is 7 (Sunday), and your date column is Sunday then your `dw` is `1`, and your known Monday is `2`.
  - This means the result of the `dw_for_known_monday - dw_for_your_date` is `+1` rather than `-6`
  - This would then mean that DATEADD will roll your date forwards to the following Monday rather than backwards to the previous Monday
  - If we subtract `7` off it then the result would definitely be negative, but then we wouldn't want your Mondays (which are 0 days different from the known Monday) to end up doing a `DATEADD` of `-7`, so we modulo the result by 7.
  - This turns any problematic `-7` into `0`, which means your `DATEADD` will only ever have a "number of days" argument between `-6` and `0`
- `DATEADD(DAY, (DATEPART(dw, '2001-01-01') - DATEPART(dw, YOUR_COLUMN)-7)%7, YOUR_COLUMN)` - we then `DATEADD` the (negative) number of days from the above step

If you want to roll your date backwards to e.g. a Sunday, change the date `2001-01-01` to a date that is a known Sunday (like `2000-12-31`), etc