# How to sort date in mssqlserver

Tags: sql-server

I want to get distinct dates from my dbtable named tblFormno2 in an ascending order.For that i've written the following query but its not working properly.

Column date_submit is declared as datetime

```
select distinct (convert(nvarchar(100),date_submit,103)) as dob from 
tblFormno2 order by dob asc
```

Here the the output is shown as

```
05/07/2011
06/03/2011
06/07/2011
07/04/2011
08/01/2012
```

instead of

```
06/03/2011
07/04/2011
05/07/2011
06/07/2011
08/01/2012
```

How to solve this problem ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
select convert(nvarchar(10), date_submit_inner, 103) as date_submit from 
(
    select distinct date_submit as date_submit_inner from tblFormno2
) as T
order by T.date_submit_inner asc
```

Comment: Here the problem is duplication of date occurs.I think its because when we take distinct here same date is occuring twice in the case where time is different.

Comment: You will get dups is there are different *times* for the same date of so change to `select distinct cast(date_submit as date) as date_submit_inner from tblFormno2`

Comment: I'm getting an error as "Type date is not a defined system type.".I think there's no datatype such as date in mssqlserver2005

Comment: In that case you want `select distinct dateadd(d, 0, datediff(d, 0, date_submit)) as date_submit_inner from tblFormno2`

Comment: Thank you alex for this wonderful answer.Im new to sql ,so can you help me in understanding this dateadd function

Comment: Its just a quick way to strip the time from a datetime; `datediff(d, 0, date_submit)` is an int with days since 01/01/1901, then use `datediff` to convert that int back to a datetime that conveniently has no time part (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639051/what-is-the-best-way-to-truncate-a-date-in-sql-server).

Answer (score 1):

Your `order by` is not sorting by `date_submit` from the table.  Is is sorting by the named output column of `date_submit`.  If you specific the table name in the order by it should work.  If that doesn't work, then try giving the output a different name than the table column.

```
select distinct (Convert(nvarchar(100),date_submit,103)) as date_submit  
from tblFormno2 
order by tblFormno2.date_submit asc
```

Comment: Yes its not sorting by the date_submit from the table.I've modified the above query to avoid confusion.I tried this but i'm getting error as "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified."

Answer (score -1):

```
create table #temp
(
 DT varchar(20)
)

Insert into #temp(DT)values('13/05/2011')
Insert into #temp(DT)values('03/06/2011')
Insert into #temp(DT)values('07/06/2011')
Insert into #temp(DT)values('04/07/2011')
Insert into #temp(DT)values('01/08/2011')

Select * from #temp

Below are the database records...
```

---

[image]

```
select (convert(varchar,Dt,107)) t into #t from  #temp

select * from #t
```

[image]

```
drop table #temp
drop table #t
```