# setting GETDATE() to only give out day on default value in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, getdate

I'm trying to set a column with a default value or binding of the current date in MSSQL.
I'm currently using `GETDATE()`, but this gives me the timestamp with the hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds, I only need the day part (2015-03-05).

Only results I found on the web were these of changing it in the SELECT statement.

Comment: cast(getdate() as date), You can't change the setting to get a different result for getdate()

Comment: The field itself should be defined as type Date, not any other data type that stores the time element. `cast(getdate() as date)` is great, but also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639051/what-is-the-best-way-to-truncate-a-date-in-sql-server for alternatives

Comment: Did you try using the same suggestions you found for SELECT statements in the DEFAULT statement?

Comment: Yes, of course, I get an error stating that the input is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use it in a date context SQL Server will auto cast it for you

```
DECLARE @date DATE = GETDATE();

SELECT  @date

-- result: 2015-03-05
```

or you could simply use a cast

```
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
```

**EDIT:**

I'm still not sure if I get what you want, but if you want to do it as a default constraints it works the same way:

```
create table #table
(
    id int,
    insertDate date default GETDATE()
)

insert into #table (id) values (1)

select top 1 insertDate from #table

-- result: 2015-03-05
```

Comment: I'd like it to happen when I insert a value, on the deafult binding, if that's possible, not on SELECT.

Comment: if the column of your insert is a date type it will also auto cast it for you

Comment: I've edited my post, because I guess you want to have this as a default constraint right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store only date, excluding time you can use this:

```
CREATE TABLE #dts(id INT IDENTITY, d_date datetime2 DEFAULT CONVERT(char(10), GETDATE(), 126))
INSERT #dts DEFAULT VALUES 
SELECT * FROM #dts
```

However it will return you zeroes instead of time, as seen here:

```
id  d_date
-------------------------------
1   2015-03-05 00:00:00.0000000
```

You can remove unwanted characters using LEFT function:

```
SELECT id, LEFT(d_date, 10) FROM #dts
```

It will return you:

```
id  d_date
--------------
1   2015-03-05
```

You could achieve this by using varchar as datatype, but i dont think it would be appropiate solution and it's better to format date in select statement. But if you really need it, then this works:

```
CREATE TABLE #dts(id INT IDENTITY, d_date VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT CONVERT(char(10), GETDATE(), 126))
INSERT #dts DEFAULT VALUES 
SELECT * FROM #dts
```

**Output:**

```
id  d_date
--------------
1   2015-03-05
```

Comment: Using LEFT(date, 10) returns the following: Mar  5 201

Comment: Maybe because I'm using different environment settings. Try this: `SELECT id, LEFT(CONVERT(char(10), d_date, 126)), 10) FROM #dts`

Answer (score 0):

Set your default value on the column to

`(CONVERT([date],getdate(),0))`

I have used it many times

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problem is simple. Change the format of the column that is going to hold the value to a `DATE` (as opposed to a data type that will hold the time portion, i.e: `DATETIME`).

Then set the default to `GETDATE()` and because the destination column is a `DATE` the time portion will be stripped off for you.

Take this sample code:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (id INT, CreatedDate DATE DEFAULT GETDATE())

INSERT INTO #temp ( id)
VALUES ( 1 ),( 2 ),( 3 )

SELECT * FROM #temp

DROP TABLE #temp
```

**Output:**

```
id  CreatedDate
1   2015-03-05
2   2015-03-05
3   2015-03-05
```

Comment: I have no "date" datatype, only "datetime"

Comment: @NirTzezana what version of sql server are you using? if you're not interested in the time portion, change it's data type to `date` if it's available.

Answer (score 0):

In other ways to convert `DATETIME` to `DATE` (get only date without time) you can use `CAST` to `DATE` format.

`SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)`

In your case you can set default value type `DATE` without CASTing.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(
   Id INT,
   ..... ,
   CurrentDate DATE DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONVERT()` to get date in different formats. From http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp :

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),GETDATE())
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),10)
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110)
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),6)
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),106)
CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),GETDATE(),113)
```

gives you the following results:

```
Nov 04 2011 11:45 PM
11-04-11
11-04-2011
04 Nov 11
04 Nov 2011
04 Nov 2011 11:45:34:243
```