# Query to get the first day of the month not working with DATEADD

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dateadd

I've been writing queries to truncate the time from a given datetime for years now, based on answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2639057/3063706) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/113055/3063706) (and many other places), that groups a couple functions like

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 0, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate()))
```

and it always gives the right answer.

I figured I could translate the same logic to finding the first of the current month by using `month` instead of `day`, but it's giving me a weird date for the result: **1903-10-17**, instead of **2015-05-01**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My parameters have always been in the wrong order.**

It turns out the format for `DATEADD` I've been using all these years is wrong, and it's only been working because it's using the `day` datepart.  Casting an int to a date increments the day:

```
SELECT CAST(0 AS datetime) = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
SELECT CAST(1 AS datetime) = '1900-01-02 00:00:00.000'
SELECT CAST(2 AS datetime) = '1900-01-03 00:00:00.000'
```

I should be using `DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, getdate()), 0)` - the parameters are *(datepart, number, **date**)*, as laid out [here at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx).

Writing it as `SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)` gives the expected result of **2015-05-01**.

Comment: A good chunk of our servers are still running 2005, so I don't think that'll work for us in general, but I'll take another look at your post, @AaronBertrand.

Comment: And you only have to replace the second `GETDATE()`, not the first. Also see [this](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-trim-time-from-datetime) and [this](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/trim-time) for discussions about truncating the time.