# Find Distinct Records over a period of a month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table called `DataFile`. This keeps all my data records that get stored in a daily bases.

Data in this table looks like the below:

```
Id      ConfigAccountId Shelf       FileIdentifier  Created
5356341 23              BSAS020006  C200094         28/01/2013
5356342 23              BSAS020006  C200095         28/01/2013
5356343 23              BSAS020006  C200096         28/01/2013
5356344 23              BSAS020006  C200097         28/01/2013
5356345 23              BSAS020006  C200098         28/01/2013
5356346 23              BSAS020006  C200099         28/01/2013
5356347 23              BSAS020006  C200100         28/01/2013
5356348 23              BSAS020006  C200101         28/01/2013
5356349 23              BSAS020006  C200102         28/02/2013
5356350 23              BSAS020006  C200103         28/02/2013
5356351 23              BSAS020006  C200104         28/02/2013
5356352 23              BSAS020006  C200105         28/02/2013
5356353 23              BSAS020006  C200106         28/02/2013
5356354 23              BSAS020006  C200107         28/02/2013
5356355 23              BSAS020007  C200108         28/02/2013
5356356 23              BSAS020007  C200109         28/02/2013
```

If you look at the data, the `shelf` column will change number only when it is full, however I need to know how many unique `shelf` codes I have for the month. The problem is that `shelf` `BSAS020006` runs over two month period so if I run a distinct for `February` it will count `shelf` `BSAS020006` again(I hope I'm making sense). I need a unique `Shelf` count every month. So if a `shelf` number has already been reported on in `Jan`, and it runs over to `Feb` it must only show the count for `Jan`.

This is the code I have so far:

```
select distinct Shelf
from DataFile
where Created Between convert(datetime, '2015-10-01 00:00:01', 102) and 
                      convert(Datetime, '2015-10-31 23:59:59', 102)
```

My Output must show, But please note that a shelf can run over to a new month, and therefore must not be shown in that month as well.

```
Month    Shelf Count
January       15
February      16
March         10
```

Comment: what *exactly* is the output you're looking for? (and show the relevant input that will generate this output)

Comment: what output are you getting right now?

Comment: No, you didn't. Read [ask]. You need to show an explicit example of the input (relevant rows in the table) and an explicit matching output (exact rows, with columns & values, that you want in the output). Then you need to show what you tried, where it got you, and why that's wrong.

Comment: If you notice from the answers you got, people are ***guessing*** what you want, and that's not good.

Comment: it is simple.also put and not exists in you query.

Comment: @Amit detailed output added as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think a combination of distinct and min before counting will work for you:

```
SELECT COUNT(Shelf) AS UniqueCodesForShelf, FirstMonthForShelf AS Month
FROM
(
    SELECT Shelf, MIN(AllMonthsForShelf) AS FirstMonthForShelf
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            Shelf,
            DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, Created), 0) AS AllMonthsForShelf
        FROM DataFile
    ) AS T1
    GROUP BY Shelf
) AS T2
GROUP BY FirstMonthForShelf
```

The output of the Month column is the date of the first day of the month.

Comment: Hi @dst, correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see a table selected in your script?

Comment: @user3309798: thanks for that. I've edited my answer.

Comment: thank you for that, I get the following error Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.

Comment: @ dst, I see what you mean with the 12 month period, because I have date from 2012  till present, is there anyway we can report it to show the month, year and count?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639051/what-is-the-best-way-to-truncate-a-date-in-sql-server for example gives a few ways to do that. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thinking about this some more, I think the innermost DISTINCT is redundant - you can remove it and replace it with the MIN(DATEADD(...)) and it should give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I woukld suggest iterating through a range of dates and populating a temp table with "Shelf" only when it does not already exist in the temp table.

Something like this  (untidy and untested)....

```
DECLARE @fromDate DateTime = 'A date in the past'

DECLARE @startDateTime DateTime =  DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @fromDate), 0) ;
DECLARE @periodEnd DateTime;

Create TABLE #tmpShelf ( perisodStart DateTime, PeriodEnd DateTime, shelf nvarchar(100));

WHILE @startDateTime <= GetDate()
BEGIN
  SET @periodEnd = DATEADD( MONTH, 1, @startDateTime)

  INSERT INTO #tmpShelf SELECT @startDateTime, @periodEnd, DISTINCT Shelf
  FROM DataFile D 
  WHERE D.Created BETWEEN @startDateTime AND @periodEnd
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #tmpShelf WHERE shelf = D.shelf)

  SET @startDateTime = DATEADD( MONTH, 1, @startDateTime)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Declare @To Datetime='2013-02-28 23:59:59'
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    Id INT
    ,ConfigAccountId INT
    ,Shelf VARCHAR(20)
    ,FileIdentifier VARCHAR(20)
    ,Created DATETIME
    )

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES

(5356341, 23,'BSAS020006','C200094','01/28/2013')
,(5356342, 23,'BSAS020006','C200095','01/28/2013')
,(5356343, 23,'BSAS020006','C200096','01/28/2013')
,(5356344, 23,'BSAS020006','C200097','01/28/2013')
,(5356345, 23,'BSAS020006','C200098','01/28/2013')
,(5356346, 23,'BSAS020006','C200099','01/28/2013')
,(5356347, 23,'BSAS020006','C200100','01/28/2013')
,(5356348, 23,'BSAS020006','C200101','01/28/2013')
,(5356349, 23,'BSAS020006','C200102','02/28/2013')
,(5356350, 23,'BSAS020006','C200103','02/28/2013')
,(5356351, 23,'BSAS020006','C200104','02/28/2013')
,(5356352, 23,'BSAS020006','C200105','02/28/2013')
,(5356353, 23,'BSAS020006','C200106','02/28/2013')
,(5356354, 23,'BSAS020006','C200107','02/28/2013')
,(5356355, 23,'BSAS020007','C200108','02/28/2013')
,(5356356, 23,'BSAS020007','C200109','02/28/2013')
SELECT *
FROM @t A
WHERE Created BETWEEN @From
        AND @To
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT Shelf
        FROM @t B
        WHERE B.Shelf = A.Shelf
            AND Created NOT BETWEEN @From
                AND @To
        )
```

Comment: Hi @KumarHarsh,, thank you for your response, will I have to add the data every date as shown above?