# SQL query to find current month from date

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: The table is here]

The question is to Produce a list of the latest movies by genres for the current month. How to find the current month from the Date???

Comment: Which rdbms are you using (you've tagged two different ones here), and did you try googling for an answer?

Comment: show text non img ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to truncate a date in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639051/what-is-the-best-way-to-truncate-a-date-in-sql-server)

Comment: What is the datatype of `ReleaseDate`?

Comment: The data type for release date is Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [DATEPART()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

```
Select
    *
From YourTable
Where 
    datepart(month,ReleaseDate) = datepart(month,getdate())
and datepart(year,ReleaseDate) = datepart(year,getdate())
Order by Genre, ReleaseDate desc
```

Comment: Thank you!!! It worked!!  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(TO_CHAR(now(),'YYYYMMDD'),5,2)
```

In which:

Format to date and you get only the month