# Using TRUNC function from Oracle in T-SQL

Tags: oracle, function, datetime, procedure

So I'm in the process of doing Procedures and Functions conversion from Oracle to MS SQL Server 2012.

In Oracle I have the following select statement:

```
--Add 5 months less one day to the quarter, ie 1/1/09 returns 5/31/09 
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(to_date('1-dec-2017'), 'q'), 5) - 1  FROM DUAL;
```

And I get the following value in return:

```
28-FEB-18
```

I am trying to convert it into MS SQL Server like:

```
SELECT dateadd(m, 0, convert(datetime, dateadd(q, 5,convert(datetime,'1-dec-2017')))) - 1
```

And I get the following result: `2019-02-28 00:00:00.000`

I am not sure why I am getting an additional year in T-SQL. I will appreciate some assistance. thank you.

Comment: You are adding 5 quarters, not 5 months.

Comment: I tried: `SELECT dateadd(m, 5, convert(datetime,'1-dec-2017')) - 1`
I get in return 2018-04-30 in TSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To truncate to quarter, see [What is the best way to truncate a date in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639051/what-is-the-best-way-to-truncate-a-date-in-sql-server#2639057)

```
SELECT DATEADD(Q, DATEDIFF(Q, 0, convert(datetime,'1-dec-2017')), 0)
```

Add five months.

```
SELECT DATEADD(M, 5, DATEADD(Q, DATEDIFF(Q, 0, convert(datetime,'1-dec-2017')), 0))
```

Subtract a day

```
SELECT DATEADD(M, 5, DATEADD(Q, DATEDIFF(Q, 0, convert(datetime,'1-dec-2017')), 0)) - 1
SELECT DATEADD(D, -1, DATEADD(M, 5, DATEADD(Q, DATEDIFF(Q, 0, convert(datetime,'1-dec-2017')), 0)))
```