# Query with sql datepart

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table with two column as :

```
serial_number
1
2
3

dateOfAppoinement
2011-06-30 00:39:04.130
2011-06-30 00:40:01.130
2011-06-30 00:49:04.130
```

I want to get the highest serial_number of a day. I have to avoid the time part. I'm just using the date part.

Can anyone tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my answer to use Convert like snkmchnb suggested.  However in SQL Server 2008 there is a DATE datatype that is just the date portion of the year so you don't have to specify the 120 code.  I tested this and it works perfectly and the SQL is pretty straight forward.

```
SELECT
    MAX(serial_number),
    CONVERT(DATE, dateOfAppointment) as [Day]
FROM
    #TempSerialsByDate
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(DATE, dateOfAppointment)
```

Comment: i just need the maximum serial number of a day..i tried with your approach...not working..any suggestion?

Comment: Try it now.  It works, I just made a temp table locally and tried it.  The query previously only worked per month.

Comment: yes..it works for me....nice query..100% perfect......i must invite you for a coffee...

Comment: Please take a look at this query : it's another better solution : select MAX(sl_no) as sl_no  from Appointment where CAST(appointment_date_time as DATE)='2011-06-30'

Answer (score 0):

I think this select solves your problem, can't figure if it is the best way:

```
select dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0, dateOfAppoinement ))
from your_table where serial_number = (select max(serial_number) form your_table)
```

How truncate date in sql server can be found here:
[How can I truncate a datetime in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923295/how-to-truncate-a-datetime-in-sql-server)

Comment: Sai's query seem a better way

Comment: i am getting error after the where clause..and i want the serial_number as select result..please keep that in mind