# Group by datetime ignoring time portion

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, time, group-by

Is it possible to write a Microsoft SQL query that will group by a `datetime` data-type but ignoring the time part such as the hour and minute?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? It does matter for this particular question.  (it is *possible* in all versions of SQL Server, but there is a better solution in 2008+)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to truncate a datetime in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923295/how-to-truncate-a-datetime-in-sql-server) and [many others](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=018205968162215846785%3A7n6ajnwyz-i&ie=UTF-8&q=sql+server+truncate+%28datetime|time%29&sa=Search&siteurl=www.google.com%2Fcse%2Fhome%3Fcx%3D018205968162215846785%3A7n6ajnwyz-i)

Comment: @AndriyM - Grouping by the `date` part of a `datetime` does present a specific optimisation problem beyond just truncating the date part though. e.g. compare the plans for `CREATE TABLE T1(D DATETIME2 PRIMARY KEY);CREATE TABLE T2(D DATE, T TIME, PRIMARY KEY(D,T));SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T1 GROUP BY CAST(D AS DATE) OPTION (ORDER GROUP);SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T2 GROUP BY D OPTION (ORDER GROUP)`

Comment: @MartinSmith: Ah, good point! Such a good example of over-eagerness in spotting an easy duplicate, that close vote of mine! Nevertheless, it is possible that I wouldn't have recognised the peculiarity you've just pointed out had I trodden on this question today, so thank you for marking the difference for me (and indeed for everyone else).

Answer (score 13):

If you are on SQL Server 2008 this is simple.

```
GROUP BY CAST(YourCol AS Date)
```

For previous versions you can use

```
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, YourCol)
```

However neither of these will be able to leverage the fact that an index on `YourCol` that is ordered by `datetime` will also be ordered by `date` and thus use a stream aggregate without a sort operation.

On SQL Server 2008+ you might consider indexing `(date,time)` rather than `datetime` to facilitate this type of query.

Either by simply storing it as two separate components and possibly providing a calculated column that recombines the parts (a `datetime2` is stored the same as a `date` and a `time` so this won't consume any more space except for if the additional column pushes the `NULL_BITMAP` onto a new byte.).

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
YourDateCol date,
YourTimeCol time,
YourDateTimeCol AS  DATEADD(day, 
                            DATEDIFF(DAY,0,YourDateCol), 
                            CAST(YourTimeCol AS DATETIME2(7)))
/*Other Columns*/
)
```

Or alternatively you could store it combined in the base table and have the indexes use calculated columns that split it out.

An example of this approach

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
DT DATETIME2,
D AS CAST(DT AS DATE),
T AS CAST(DT AS TIME)
)

CREATE INDEX IX1 ON T(DT);

SELECT COUNT(*), 
       CAST(DT AS DATE)
FROM T
GROUP BY CAST(DT AS DATE)

CREATE INDEX IX2 ON T(D,T);

SELECT COUNT(*), 
       CAST(DT AS DATE)
FROM T
GROUP BY CAST(DT AS DATE)

DROP TABLE T
```

[image]

Comment: `GROUP BY DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, YourCol)` would probably also be enough in this case...

Comment: @Tomalak - Good point. That will return an `int` that is sufficient to `group by` and no reason to convert back to `datetime` except for display purposes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large table and want grouping to happen *fast*, you cannot rely grouping on an expression.

Create an additional datetime column on your table and have it filled by a trigger that calculates the base date from you "real" date:

```
UPDATE
  MyTable
SET
  EffectiveDate = DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, t.RecordDate))
FROM
  MyTable t
  INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.RowID = t.RowID
```

Then put an index on `EffectiveDate` and grouping (and searching) will be a lot faster.

Comment: For SQL Server 2008 casting by date [is sargable](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/526431/make-more-functions-sargable) though I've not checked whether this gets leveraged in `group by` queries.

Comment: @Martin Interesting, I didn't know that. But it would still trigger a table scan when there is no index on the column, wouldn't it?

Comment: Why a trigger and not a computed column? `EffectiveDate AS CONVERT(DATETIME, DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, t.RecordDate)))` - this column could be persisted and indexed as well to remove any doubts about sargability, without paying for the overhead of a trigger.

Comment: @Aaron That's right. SQL Server 2000 does not support indexes on computed columns with datetime values (for some reason date functions are non-deterministic there). This has been fixed in later versions but I still think "trigger" at first. ;)