# How to average/sum data in a day in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, aggregate-functions, aggregation

I'm trying to average data in SQL Server 2005 in a day. Here is what my database look like this if I use simple query as

```
SELECT timestamp, FEED
FROM ROASTER_FEED
ORDER timestamp
```

Data:

```
timestamp               Feed    
02/07/2011 12:00:01     1246   
02/07/2011 12:00:01     1234    
02/07/2011 12:00:01     1387    
02/07/2011 12:00:02     1425   
02/07/2011 12:00:03     1263   
...    
02/07/2011 11:00:01     1153    
02/07/2011 11:00:01     1348    
02/07/2011 11:00:01     1387    
02/07/2011 11:00:02     1425    
02/07/2011 11:00:03     1223    
....   
03/07/2011 12:00:01     1226    
03/07/2011 12:00:01     1245    
03/07/2011 12:00:01     1384    
03/07/2011 12:00:02     1225    
03/07/2011 12:00:03     1363
```

I don't know how to average the feed when someone select a date in a month and it give display the average/sum of that day only.

For example, in the outcome, if I select day as 02/07/2011. It would give me something like this:

```
02/07/2011 1234 (average value/or sum)
```

Comment: is this data in a database, in a file, or what?  What language are you using?

Comment: What language? What platform? Is this a SQL question? If so, what server and version?

Comment: We can't help you unless you tell us more information. Is this Excel? Access? MS SQL Server?

Comment: what type of DB is this? MS SQL? MYSQL? Access?

Comment: What is the Drye_data table structure? please give some example records from it. And put sql in the tags.

Comment: that is not a database. Do you mean MS SQL 2005? it is possible to connect MS SQL Management Studio 2005 to a MS SQL 2008 database (among others)

Comment: Any particular reason to be grouping by timestamp? Why are you converting it to a char? Seems to me that the you shouldn't use group by.

Comment: @daniloquio Not really. I just left it as how it showed up. The Group by doesn't affect the issue I'm having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7:40am is 460 minutes after 00:00

7:40pm is 1180 minutes after 00:00

midnigth is 1440 minutes after 00:00

And DATEPART(hh, SomeDate)*60 + DATEPART(mi, SomeDate) gives you the amount of minutes after 00:00 for a given SomeDate

So, you could use:

```
SELECT
    AVG(Temperature) As Dayshift
FROM Drye_data
WHERE DATEPART(hh, TimeStamp)*60 + DATEPART(mi, TimeStamp) BETWEEN 460 AND 1180
      AND @SelectedDate = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(TimeStamp AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
```

and for the Nightshift:

```
    SELECT
    AVG(Temperature) As Nigthshift
FROM Drye_data
WHERE (
        (DATEPART(hh, TimeStamp)*60 + DATEPART(mi, TimeStamp) BETWEEN 0 AND 460)
        AND @SelectedDate = DATEADD(dd, 1, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(TimeStamp AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME))
      )
      OR 
      (
         (DATEPART(hh, TimeStamp)*60 + DATEPART(mi, TimeStamp) BETWEEN 1180 AND 1440) AND @SelectedDate = CAST(FLOOR(CAST(TimeStamp AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
      )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, I didn't think about break it down like that. It's so cool. However I forgot that the report has to be able to chose any day (another person can select a day, and the report is coming out on that day). Where would I put @selectdate? Thank you SO MUCH

Comment: You mean that the report is the average temperature for each shift in a specific day?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Each shift in a specific day. And the day is chosen by viewrer. And the Night shift is tricky, because it's half of today, and half of the next day

Comment: @Thao - I edited the answer with what I think is the solution. I used this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923295/how-to-truncate-a-datetime-in-sql-server to truncate the datetime to day level.

Comment: DAYSHIFT works like a charm. So amazing.
However, Nightshift is a little off. Since it's from 7:40PM of today until 7:40AM next day. For example, Night shift of 30 Sept 2011 is from 7:40PM of 30 Sept 2011 until 7:40AM of 1 Oct 2011.
Can I use (DATEPART(hh, TimeStamp)*60 + DATEPART(mi, TimeStamp) Between 1180 to 1900 AND @selecteddate = ....

Comment: @Thao There were an error on the nigthshift part, I edited it and is corrected. Please test it :D

Comment: Something wrong with NightShift. I'm only able to get the average of 7PM to 11h59PM. It doesnt average the next morning :(

Comment: @Thao, this should work fine now; the selectedDate filter was not clear. You fit a lot in an expression we have here in Colombia: "juum pero usted pide más que deme!" Just joking, no ofense :D

Comment: AWESOME........... If you were here, I take you out for a meal :) (Sorry, I can't drink, get drunk too quick). But you can :)

Comment: Ok, no free meal for me, but at least fix the tags on your question jeje. By clicking edit you can do it and set the tags to sql/ sql-server / tsql / time . Good nigth.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility, if you need to do this often enough: add three computed columns for day, month, year to your table. Those columns are computed automatically based on the `timestamp` column, and they're just integer values, so they're easy to use in a `GROUP BY`.

To do this, use these T-SQL statements:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ROASTER_FEED ADD TSDay AS DAY(timestamp) PERSISTED
ALTER TABLE dbo.ROASTER_FEED ADD TSMonth AS MONTH(timestamp) PERSISTED
ALTER TABLE dbo.ROASTER_FEED ADD TSYear AS YEAR(timestamp) PERSISTED
```

Now, you can easily select your data based on any day you wish:

```
SELECT TSDay, TSMonth, TSYear, SUM(FEED)   -- use AVG(FEED) for average values
FROM dbo.ROASTER_FEED
WHERE TSYear = 2011 AND TSMonth = 8   -- or whatever you want to grab from the table!
ORDER BY timestamp
GROUP BY TSDay, TSMonth, TSYear
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm not a SQL guy, but I'd expect something like:

```
SELECT SUM(ValueColumn) AS Total, AVG(ValueColumn) AS Average FROM YourTableName
WHERE RecordedTime >= @StartTime AND RecordedTime < @EndTime
```

(where @StartTime and @EndTime are parameters filled in by the calling code).

(It's not clear to me what will happen if no records are found... worth checking out.)

Comment: I wish SQL is smarter in the time frame issue. :( I tried that. @ starttime and @ Endtime is only date selection, not time. I'm stucked

Comment: @Thao: That's not SQL's fault - you should make the calling code pass in the right DATETIME value. You probably *could* make it perform the addition in the SQL, but personally I'd do it in the calling code instead. It's not clear to me what your calling code *is* here - can you give more context?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little slow. I'm a new learner. This is what I wrote. And it gives me from 12AM to 11:59:59PM 

SELECT     CONVERT(char(10), timestamp, 105) AS 'day time', AVG(REPORTSROASTERFEED_RATE_VAL0) AS 'AVERAGE FEED DAY'

FROM         NIGHT_SHIFT
GROUP BY CONVERT(char(10), timestamp, 105)
HAVING      (CONVERT(char(10), timestamp, 105) = @selectdate)

Comment: @Thao: No, ideally you shouldn't need to do any conversions - you should be able to pass in the right time *as a timestamp*. Avoid conversions wherever possible.

Comment: Thank you so much for quick help. So I tried again today, and here is what I came up with, of course, still problem. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615285/how-to-average-data-from-7am-to-7pm-of-one-day-in-sql-2005

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(timestamp) as NumValues, 
       SUM(Feed) as ValuesSum, 
       AVG(Feed) as Average

  FROM ROASTER_FEED

 WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '1/1/2011'  AND '9/15/2011'
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It give me 614 same answer for every tick that timestamp recorded

Answer (score 0):

To get the average feed for one day you can use this.

```
declare @Date datetime

set @Date = '20110702'

select @Date as [timestamp], avg(FEED) as AvgFeed
from ROASTER_FEED
where [timestamp] >= @Date and 
      [timestamp] < dateadd(day, 1, @Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT timestamp, sum(FEED)
FROM ROASTER_FEED
WHERE timestamp=....
GROUP BY timestamp
```

it could be slow if you are handling alot of data, in this case you should considering an additional table which holds the pre-calculated values for each day.

Answer (score 0):

@marc_s hit upon the preferred solution of using a computed columns to handle this but to do it on-the-fly, cast your timestamp data to shear off the time component. In my example, I cast it to a 10 character field that contains the 0 padded date.

```
;
WITH ROASTER_FEED ([timestamp],[Feed]) AS
(
SELECT CAST('02/07/2011 12:00:01' AS datetime),1246   
UNION ALL SELECT '02/07/2011 12:00:01',1234    
UNION ALL SELECT '02/07/2011 12:00:01',1387    
UNION ALL SELECT '02/07/2011 12:00:02',1425   
UNION ALL SELECT '02/07/2011 12:00:03',1263   

UNION ALL SELECT '02/07/2011 11:00:01',1153    
UNION ALL SELECT '02/07/2011 11:00:01',1348    
UNION ALL SELECT '02/07/2011 11:00:01',1387    
UNION ALL SELECT '02/07/2011 11:00:02',1425    
UNION ALL SELECT '02/07/2011 11:00:03',1223    

UNION ALL SELECT '03/07/2011 12:00:01',1226    
UNION ALL SELECT '03/07/2011 12:00:01',1245    
UNION ALL SELECT '03/07/2011 12:00:01',1384    
UNION ALL SELECT '03/07/2011 12:00:02',1225    
UNION ALL SELECT '03/07/2011 12:00:03',1363
)
SELECT
    -- Shear off the time value by forcing the date into date values
    -- If this was SQL Server 2008+, we'd just cast to date type and
    -- be done with it
    -- Chart for convert options
    -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx
    CONVERT(char(10), RF.[timestamp], 121) AS [timestamp]
,   COUNT(1) AS row_counts
,   SUM(RF.Feed) as ValuesSum 
,   AVG(RF.Feed) as Average
FROM 
    ROASTER_FEED RF
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(char(10), RF.[timestamp], 121)
```

Results in

```
timestamp   row_counts   ValuesSum  Average
2011-02-07  10           13091      1309
2011-03-07  5            6443       1288
```

Comment: Thank you. What I have been trying to search is this one

CONVERT(char(10), RF.[timestamp], 121) AS [timestamp]

Answer (score 0):

Check out some of the tutorials from here 
http://www.smallsql.de/doc/sql-functions/date-time/index.html 
ive been looking for something simialr and found that site useful and thought it may help

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.