# SQL Report 2005, How to sum within a specific time

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to average/sum data in a day in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450463/how-to-average-sum-data-in-a-day-in-sql-server-2005)

I have a data base "Shift", where it is recorded every minute. I have to sum the data by shift.

And Night Shift starts from 7:15PM of the previous day to 7:15 AM of that day. I need to write it somehow that when someone select a day, it will pop up a sum/average data within that time frame.

Please Help. Thank you very much.