# How to average data from 7AM to 7PM of one day in SQL 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to average/sum data in a day in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450463/how-to-average-sum-data-in-a-day-in-sql-server-2005)

I have a set of data which is called Dryer_Data. This data is recorded every minute. I need to average it ***Dayshift***: from  7:40AM to 7:40PM everyday, and ***Nightshift*** from 7:40PM to 7:40AM the next day

timestamp                      Temperature
02/07/2011 12:01:00 AM            1246
02/07/2011 12:02:00 AM            1234
02/07/2011 12:03:00 AM            1387
02/07/2011 12:04:00 AM            1425
02/07/2011 12:05:00 AM            1263
...
02/07/2011 11:02:00 PM            1153
02/07/2011 11:03:00 PM            1348
02/07/2011 11:04:00 PM            1387
02/07/2011 11:05:00 PM            1425
02/07/2011 11:06:00 PM            1223
....
03/07/2011 12:01:00 AM            1226
03/07/2011 12:02:00 AM            1245
03/07/2011 12:03:00 AM            1384
03/07/2011 12:04:00 AM            1225
03/07/2011 12:05:00 AM            1363

I did do something like

For NIGHTShift:

```
    Select  CONVERT(char(10), timestamp, 121), average(temperature)
From Drye_data

Group by   CONVERT(char(10), timestamp, 121) 

Having   CONVERT(char(10), timestamp, 121)   BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, 40, DATEADD(hour, 19, @selectdate)) AND DATEADD(minute, 40, DATEADD(hour, 31, @selectdate)))
```

***I believe it only gives me data that from 12AM to 7:40AM.***

For DAYShift I did:

```
Select  CONVERT(char(10), timestamp, 121), average(temperature)

From Drye_data

Group by   CONVERT(char(10), timestamp, 121) 

Having   CONVERT(char(10), timestamp, 121)   BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, 40, DATEADD(hour, 7, @selectdate)) AND DATEADD(minute, 40, DATEADD(hour, 19, @selectdate)))
```

***Of course, it doesn't give me any value.***

Or instead of using `CONVERT`, I used `DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, timestamp), 0)`, it gives the answer of every hour (multiple answer for every hour). But I only need 1 result.

Or when I used DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, timestamp), 0), it gives me the same answer with CONVERT.
Please help.... THANK YOU VERY MUCH.