# Selecting date value without time in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, datetime

I am facing a problem selecting the date in SQL Server 2005. The table name is Softskill and the column name is insertdate. The data is stored as 2011-09-22 08:50:28.000 in this format.

To select, I am passing values from the front end as '2011-09-22', I mean the date only.

I tried to use

```
SELECT INSERTDATE FROM SOFTSKILL WHERE INSERTDATE = '2011-09-22'.
```

But it is not showing the record. May I know which format the column is following and is there any way to retrieve data by using only date?

Answer (score 3):

You want to search for a range of times that encompass the day. Something like:

```
SELECT INSERTDATE 
    FROM SOFTSKILL 
    WHERE INSERTDATE >= '2011-09-22 00:00:00'
        AND INSERTDATE < '2011-09-23 00:00:00'
```

You could also apply functions to `INSERTDATE` to extract just the date portion, but that will make the query [nonsargable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable).

Comment: Hi i am passing date value from the front end, and i could not able to pass the next date also..

Comment: @NAVEENKUMAR: This is just a quick sample. You could compute the next date, right?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * 
FROM SOFTSKILL 
WHERE DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, InsertDate)) = '2011-09-22'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you need

```
SELECT INSERTDATE 
FROM SOFTSKILL 
WHERE CAST(FLOOR(CAST(INSERTDATE AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) = '2011-09-30'
```

You need to truncate INSERTDATE so its time part is 00:00:00.000; then, it will be equal to '2011-09-30' assuming INSERTDATE is '2011-09-30 XX:XX:XX.xxx'.

Comment: Related useful question about truncating datetime: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923295/how-to-truncate-a-datetime-in-sql-server