# How to set date only in SQL Server table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2005

I am using `datatime` datatype to set date in database but it gives the complete data time and hrs and minutes I want to set only date in the format of `dd-mm-yyyy`

Comment: cast(getDate() As Date) from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923295/how-can-i-truncate-a-datetime-in-sql-server

Comment: *I am using SQL Server 9.0.3042* --> that is SQL Server **2005**, not 2008 ... see [SQL Server versions and builds](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.ch/)

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps use [date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352(v=sql.100).aspx) instead of `datetime`?

Comment: Yes. See [the date and time types of SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx).

Comment: there is no such data type available for date only in sqlserver2008

Comment: Hi, the `DATE` data type was introduced in SQL Server 2008 (c.f. the link I posted which is set to SQL Server 2008 as the version). I don't think this is it but what edition are you running? Also, what [compatibility mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933794(v=sql.100).aspx) is your database in? (it wouldn't be in SQL 2005 compatibility mode by any chance? If you're in 2005 compatibility mode then the `DATE` data type won't be available - it needs to be in 2008 compatibility mode)

Comment: @ShaikhNadeem: you're said in your original post in the tags that you **are** using SQL Server **2008** ....

Comment: SQL Server 2008 does indeed have the Date datatype

Comment: i am using sql server 9.0.3042, is it the same compatible sql server 2008? or can u help me to set compatibility to 2008?

Comment: That's SQL Server 2005 (please see [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185) link). In that case then yes there is no `DATE` data type. The other answers which SO users have provided to your question, and which don't rely on the `DATE` data type, will likely be more relevant to you, then

Answer (score 2):

a) in 2008 and later, there is a `Date` datatype you can use

b) if you can't change the datatype, you can convert a `datetime` to `date` to 'truncate' the time.  e.g.: `convert( date, GETDATE() )` will return `'2013-03-27'`, and when inserted into the `datetime` column, it will have time `00:00:00.000`

c) if you simply don't want to display the time component when converting to a string, use convert with the format of your choosing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Just use `DATE` datatype instead of`DATETIME`

More on [DATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186724.aspx)

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c93ac/1)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT into myTable(dateColumn) Values (@pDate)", conn);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pDate", dt.Date.ToShortDateString());
```