# DATE from DATETIME in SQL SERVER 2005 (Without using VARCHAR)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Our application using ***SQL SERVER 2005***

I need to show **only DATE from DateTime** in GridView.

I don't want to **convert** it into any other format like `Varchar` or something. 
It should be only in **DateTime** format itself, without **Time**.

Please Help.

Comment: `dt.ToShortDateString()` in `Row_DataBound` or `M/d/yyyy`(or simply `"d"`) as [`DataFormatString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx).

Comment: I don't think it would be possible in **SQL SERVER** but you can do so **pro-grammatically**

Comment: Sorry for less information, but I need it in SQL Server itself.

Comment: Why dont you want to use the CONVERT function?

Answer (score 9):

In SQL Server, the code is

```
CAST(datediff(d,0,datetimecol) as datetime)
```

However, I doubt that does any good for a GridView, which will infer it to be a "datetime" column and show a "date + time" formatting, even if the times are ALL "00:00:00".

Answer (score 2):

Bound the DateField coloumn in Grid like below, then it works...

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Your_Date_Column" 
                    HeaderText="Date_Column" 
                    DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
```

`DataFormatString="{0:d}"` it display the Date like `3/11/2013`

Answer (score 2):

In SQL 2005 there is no way of keeping it in datetime format without the time (time is part of the datetime type), the best you could get would be something like:

```
2013-04-02 00:00:00.000
```

If you were willing to convert to VARCHAR, you could use something similar to:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111)
```

Which would display the date portion as you want it.  Otherwise, you need to move to SQL 2008+ where there is a proper date type that you can use instead.

If you need to stick with SQL 2005, the best way to achive this is to just format it in the datagrid view itself.

Comment: AFAIK, using SQL Server 2008 `DATE` datatype doesn't solve any display problems, since the underlying **`get`** function returns a .Net type of datetime, exactly the same as for the SQL `DATETIME` datatype.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to truncate a datetime so that it only returns the date as at midnight, see the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923295) - the question relates specifically to SQLServer 2008, but the answer includes details of how to achieve this in SQLServer 2005.

If you want to convert a datetime field into a date-only field - you cannot achieve this in SQLServer 2005 in SQL alone, as there is no date-only datatype - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187752%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).