# Truncate a Date/Time timestamp in C#

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, casting

I am looking to remove the time stamp from a dateTime field.

```
int[] projects = {11157, 11138};

protected void compare(System.Data.DataTable dt1, System.Data.DataTable dt2, int[] arr)
{
    differences.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    differences.Columns.Add("BRS Date", typeof(string));

    foreach (int value in arr)
    {
        DataRow[] result = dt1.Select("ChangeRequestNo = '" + arr +"' OR [GPP ID] = '" + arr + "'");
        string brs = "";
        string srs = "";
        if (result.Length > 1)
        {
            DataRow row1 = result[0];
            DataRow row2 = result[1];
            DateTime row1date = (DateTime)row1[2];
            DateTime row2date = (DateTime)row2[10];

            //Remove the Time stamp on the dateTime 
            //variable coming from the GPP Extract
            //row2date.cast(floor(cast(getdate() as float)) as datetime);

            if (row1date.Equals(row2date))
            {
                // find your Image control in the Row
                //Image image = ((Image)differences.Rows[1].FindControl("img"));
                // set the path of image
                //img.ImageUrl = "path of image";  
                brs = "True";

            }
```

This question may have been asked but through SQLserver but doesnt work for C# unless I am doing something wrong(most likely):

[How can I truncate a datetime in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923295/how-can-i-truncate-a-datetime-in-sql-server)

Basically the value that comes into my variable is "9/12/2008 12:00:00 AM" and I want "9/12/2008". I have used a few variations of the cast operator but with no luck.

```
CAST(BRSDate AS Date)          ->  Does nothing

CAST(BRSDate AS varchar(11))   ->  2009-05-26 and some dates come out as 0001-01-01
```

I apologize for the re-post but the solutions I found are not working for me unfortunately =(. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateTime` in .Net contains `TimeStamp`, you can't really truncate that part, you can use `Date` property which will have a time stamp set to `12:00:00 AM`, or you can format your date by getting only Date part and then compare it.

So for your comparison you can use:

```
if (row1date.Date.Equals(row2date.Date))
```

Comment: How would I format it to eliminate the time stamp? Cast it to a string and do myString.remove(numberOfPlaces). I guess I could also instead add the generic timestamp "12:00:00 AM" to the other BRSDate value I am comparing with.

Comment: You only have to format it for displaying, like `row1date.ToShortDateString()`or see [Custom DateTime Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), for comparison just use the `Date` property of the DateTime object like `BRSDate.Date`

Comment: row1date.ToShortDateString(); doesn't seem to do anything. I looked at the Custom DateTime Format and I used row1date.ToString("d/mm/yyyy"); and still no luck. I also tried Convert.ToDateTime(row1date);

Comment: @user1701856, `row1date.ToShortDateString();` would return a string, you need to assign that to a variable and then display that like `string str = row1date.ToShortDateString(); Console.Write(str);`