# Remove Time from DateTime values returned in Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

With the help of you guys on here, I have the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT DataLog.TimestampUTC,MeterTags.Name,DataLog.Data
FROM DataLog
INNER JOIN MeterTags
ON DataLog.MeterTagId = MeterTags.MeterTagId
WHERE DataLog.TimeStampUTC between cast(getdate() - 1 as date) and cast(getdate() as date) and
      DataLog.MeterTagId Between 416 AND 462;
```

This returns a column "TimestampUTC" with YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss. I'd like to drop the time within this column and only display YYYY-MM-DD.

Any help you could give would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: This has already been answered:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923295/how-can-i-truncate-a-datetime-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT convert(char(10), DataLog.TimestampUTC, 120) as TimestampUTC, 
MeterTags.Name,DataLog.Data
FROM DataLog
INNER JOIN MeterTags
ON DataLog.MeterTagId = MeterTags.MeterTagId
WHERE DataLog.TimeStampUTC between cast(getdate() - 1 as date) and cast(getdate() as date) and
      DataLog.MeterTagId Between 416 AND 462;
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can convert to Date

```
select Convert(Date, Convert(datetime, '2013/01/01 12:53:45'))
```

results:

```
2013-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use : 
`CAST(DataLog.TimestampUTC as date)`

The code looks like:

```
SELECT CAST(DataLog.TimestampUTC as date),MeterTags.Name,DataLog.Data
FROM DataLog
INNER JOIN MeterTags
ON DataLog.MeterTagId = MeterTags.MeterTagId
WHERE DataLog.TimeStampUTC between cast(getdate() - 1 as date) and cast(getdate() as date) and
      DataLog.MeterTagId Between 416 AND 462;
```