# SQL select value by Maximum time per day

Tags: sql

DBMS : MS SQL 2005

Consider the following table as an example

```
[CurrencyID] ---- [Rate] ---- [ExchangeDate]

USD --------------- 1 ------ 08/27/2012 11:52 AM

USD -------------- 1.1 ----- 08/27/2012 11:58 AM

USD -------------- 1.2 ----- 08/28/2012 01:30 PM

USD --------------- 1 ------ 08/28/2012 01:35 PM
```

How can i get the rate of the **latest [ExchangeDate] Per Day** for each currency ?

The output would be :

```
 [CurrencyID] ---- [Rate] ---- [ExchangeDate]

    USD ----------- 1.1 ------- 08/27/2012

    USD ------------ 1 -------- 08/28/2012
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? In what way is this problem related to .NET at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I truncate a datetime in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923295/how-can-i-truncate-a-datetime-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQL 2008, the following does the trick:

```
SELECT  CurrencyID, cast(ExchangeDate As Date) as ExchangeDate , (
          SELECT   TOP 1 Rate
          FROM     Table T2
          WHERE    cast(T2.ExchangeDate  As Date) = cast(T1.ExchangeDate  As Date)
          AND      T2.CurrencyID = T1.CurrencyID
          ORDER BY ExchangeDate DESC) As LatestRate
FROM    Table T1
GROUP BY CurrencyID, cast(T1.ExchangeDate  As Date)
```

For anything below 2008, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923295/how-can-i-truncate-a-datetime-in-sql-server).

Comment: In the sub query, you still need add the condition (T2.CurrencyID = T1.CurrencyID) right ?

Comment: @SirajMansour: Correct. Updated my answer.

Comment: You Added T2.Rate = T1.Rate, the condition is (T2.CurrencyID = T1.CurrencyID)

Comment: @SirajMansour: Right again. I wasn't really paying attention.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify which DBMS, following is Standard SQL:

```
select CurrencyID, Rate, ExchangeDate
from
  (
    select CurrencyID, Rate, ExchangeDate,
       row_number() 
       over (partition by CurrencyID, cast(ExchangeDate as date)
             order by ExchangeDate desc) as rn
    from tab
  ) as dt
 where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Could you please Write this in MS SQL syntax ?

Comment: The only part which is not SQL Server 2005 syntax is the CAST(ExchangeDate AS DATE). Steven posted a link on how to do this before SS2008: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923295/how-can-i-truncate-a-datetime-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

you can do this, read the [format](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/) here

```
select * from exchangetable order by convert(datetime, ExchangeDate, 101) ASC desc


//101 = mm/dd/yyyy - 10/02/2008
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL:

```
SELECT Rate, MAX(ExchangeDate) FROM table GROUP BY DATE(ExchangeDate)
```

Check out more information on [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

Other RDBMS's might not support this (I know that PostgreSQL doesn’t).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I thought it may be worth adding the QUALIFY clause into the mix due to how simple it is to read (without subqueries).

```
WITH example AS (
  SELECT 'USD' AS currency_id, 1 as rate, DATETIME(2012,08,27,11,52,00) as exchange_dateTime UNION ALL
  SELECT 'USD', 1.1, DATETIME(2012,08,27,11,58,00) UNION ALL
  SELECT 'USD', 1.2, DATETIME(2012,08,28,01,30,00) UNION ALL
  SELECT 'USD', 1, DATETIME(2012,08,28,01,35,00) 
)

SELECT *
FROM example
QUALIFY
  MAX(exchange_dateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY currency_id, datetime_trunc(exchange_dateTime,DAY)) = exchange_dateTime
```