# how to compare the dates in different format with the getdate() in sql server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a column, where the date values are stored in `nvarchar` data type.
The date format is `dd-mm-yy, dd.mm.yy`

Currently I am replacing the `-` with `.` and comparing with get date, as all dates formats used in other tables are in `dd.mm.yyyy` format.

Now consider a scenario where the dates may be in other formats like `dd/mm/yyyy` or other date formats, is there any way to check whether the date is valid and compare it with `getdate()`

Also I find few unknown records are also available like 57937234, I need to ignore them.

As of now I am using this query and it is working fine:

```
select 
    A.Value, replace( B.Value,'-','.') 
from 
    smpltbl as A
INNER JOIN 
    smpltbl as B ON A.MSKEY = B.MSKEY
INNER JOIN 
    smpltbl as tbl_status ON A.MSKEY = tbl_status.MSKEY
where 
    A.colname = 'XYZ' 
    AND B.colname = 'ABC' 
    AND tbl_status.colname = 'Status' 
    AND tbl_status.Value = 'OK'
    AND B.Value <> '00.00.0000' 
    and B.Value <>'..' 
    AND replace( B.Value,'-','.') < cast(convert(nvarchar, GETDATE(), 104)
```

Can someone kindly help me in accepting the dates in different format an comparing with the system date and the result must be displayed in `DD.MM.YYYY` format itself

Comment: Be advised that anything and everything you do here is going to be a hacky workaround. Make sure you have a plan to fix the root cause wherein you store your dates as **dates** (the correct data type for the field) in the future (and then clean up the old data).

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! If it's a date - **store is as a `DATE`** !

Comment: What formats *might* you have to deal with? If there's any possibility that some have been stored as `mm/dd/yyyy` (or other equivalents) then you should recognize that you may have a worse problem - the dates might *validate* but you won't know how to correctly interpret them.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the version of SQL Server you are using you can have different solutions.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103)
```

Comment: when we use 103 would return dd/mm/yyyy. which ever format the date may be stored in like dd/mm/yyyy or dd.mm.yyyy or dd-mm-yyyy. how can i compare and display the results in dd.mm.yyy . when i am using the below its displaying all the records. not records which are less than system date.     where cast(LEFT(date_b,2)+'.'+SUBSTRING(date_b,4,2)+ '.'+ RIGHT(date_b,4) as nvarchar(400))
   < cast(convert(nvarchar(400),GETDATE(),104) as nvarchar(400))

Answer (score 0):

```
cast((right(date_b,4)+'-'+substring(date_b,4,2)+'-'+left(date_b,2)+' 00:00:00.000') as datetime) 
<cast(convert(nvarchar,getdate(),104) as datetime)
```

When i used the above comparison statement, my expected and actual result are same.

Answer (score 0):

As have been said in the comments, the right way to do this would be to use the appropriate data type (`date` or `datetime`). But if you *have* to work with dates as strings, you could at least do things more simply, like this for instance:

```
CONVERT(date, date_b, 104) < CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
```

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or earlier version:

```
CONVERT(datetime, date_b, 104) < DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

The right part of the comparison in the last example is a [known method of truncation of a datetime value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923295/how-can-i-truncate-a-datetime-in-sql-server).