# SQL Server equivalent of Trunc

Tags: sql-server, oracle, equivalent

```
TRUNC(LD.FECHA_CREA)
```

I need convert it to SQL Server

Comment: the complete line is
TRUNC(LD.FECHA_CREA)  = TRUNC(SYSDATE)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I truncate a datetime in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923295/how-can-i-truncate-a-datetime-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following condition in your query :

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, LD.FECHA_CREA)) = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this equivalent in SQL Server:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, LD.FECHA_CREA));
```

Check: http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-sql-server/trunc_datetime