# How to get all records for the last 2 days in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get all the records from the last 2 days but excluding today's date. I want to get name and location where date submitted is included for the last 2 days only. The data type for `date_submitted` is `datetime`.

```
select name, location 
from myTable 
where date_submitted in (select CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME))
```

Comment: Why cast date as float?

Comment: @Zane: It seems the best performing way to truncate a date: http://stackoverflow.com/a/923322/993547.

Comment: Your reference appears to indicate that `Cast( GetDate() as Date )` is preferred as it is documented to work correctly and doesn't depend on the current binary format for `DATETIME`. It's also clearer as to your intent and clarity has considerable value in the real world.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use `in`, use `>=`. You can also use `dateadd`:

```
where date_submitted >= cast(dateadd(day, -2, getdate()) as date)
and   date_submitted < cast(getdate() as date)
```

Comment: How does that handle "excluding today's date"?

Comment: because it is date_submitted < today.