# Get the smallest datetime value for each day in SQL database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a database that are storing datetime values every minute and I wanna get the smallest value for each day.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT  lVehicleId, dtVehicleHistoryDate 
FROM  VehicleHistory
WHERE  lVehicleId = 1146 AND dtVehicleHistoryDate > '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND dtVehicleHistoryDate < '2016-01-31 00:00:00' AND ((dtTimeReceived - dtVehicleHistoryDate) > '00:30:00')
```

And my values is disposed like this:

```
Id      History date

1146    2015-01-26 23:03:50.000

1146    2015-01-26 23:04:50.000

1146    2015-01-26 23:05:50.000


1146    2015-02-19 01:33:42.000

1146    2015-02-19 01:34:42.000

1146    2015-02-19 01:35:42.000

1146    2015-02-19 01:36:42.000
```

Comment: By "smallest value" do you mean just truncate the time so you get midnight on that date?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I truncate a datetime in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923295/how-can-i-truncate-a-datetime-in-sql-server)

Comment: @hessel look answer that is correct

Comment: In this case i wanna have the result
1146        2015-01-26   23:03:50.000
and
1146        2015-02-19    01:33:42.000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by id and trunc date value:

```
SELECT t.id,cast(t.history_date as DATE),min(t.history_date)
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.id,cast(t.history_date as DATE)
```

Comment: naaaah im about to post my answer :(