# SQL check if done within a month

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, between

I'm supposed to have it present me an address of a property which had people move in within a month after it was listed.

```
SELECT rp.rp_street, rp.rp_city, rp.rp_state, rp.rp_zipcode
FROM dbo.rentproperty rp
INNER JOIN dbo.rental r
ON (rp.rp_propertyno = r.ren_rp_propertyno)
WHERE r.ren_moveindate BETWEEN rp.rp_datelisted AND rp.rp_datelisted + 30;
```

I keep getting

```
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int
```

Comment: My bad. Post Edited

Comment: Use `DATEADD`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms186819.aspx. In your case, `DATEADD(DAY, 30, rp.rp_datelisted)`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/923322/2654498

Comment: Please don't edit your question to put things like _solved_ in the title. Instead accept the answer that helped you solve the problem, or - if none of the current answer do that - post your own answer with the solution and - after the timeout - accept that answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`dateadd(day,n,col)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186819.aspx) to add days to date:

```
select rp.rp_street, rp.rp_city, rp.rp_state, rp.rp_zipcode
from dbo.rentproperty rp
inner join dbo.rental r on (rp.rp_propertyno = r.ren_rp_propertyno)
where r.ren_moveindate between rp.rp_datelisted
        and dateadd(day, 30, rp.rp_datelisted);
```