# SQL aggregate based on date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having following data in a MSSQL table. The requirement is to group the records for users which falls under same/end time duration, and sum up the Rate field.

Is there any way to achieve this via query on-the-fly?

```
Row Data
-----------------------------------------------------
RawId   Start Time      End Time        User    Rate
1       1/9/2021 14:29  1/9/2021 14:40  User-1  10
2       1/9/2021 10:37  1/9/2021 14:00  User-2  20
3       1/9/2021 14:03  1/9/2021 14:59  User-2  30
4       1/9/2021 8:51   1/9/2021 14:39  User-1  40
5       1/9/2021 14:02  1/9/2021 14:59  User-2  50

Expected Output
-----------------------------------------------------
ProID   Start Time      End Time        User    RateTotal
xx1     1/9/2021 14:29  1/9/2021 14:40  User-1  50          
xx2     1/9/2021 14:02  1/9/2021 14:59  User-2  80
xx3     1/9/2021 10:37  1/9/2021 14:00  User-2  20
```

### Business logic

**ProID xx1**: RawID 1 & 4, belong to User-1 and RawID 1 start & end time (14:29-14:40) falls within RawID 4 (08:51-14:39). In this case rates have to be added up and show only one record.

**ProID xx2**: RawID 3 & 5, belong to User-2 and RawID 3 start & end time (14:03-14:59) falls within RawID 5 (14:02-14:59). In this case rates have to be added up and show only one record.

**ProID xx3**: RawID 2 also belongs to User-2 but start & end time (10:37-14:00) doesnt fall within other User-2 records. Hence this will be considered as separate row.

Comment: I'm struggling to work out how the Start and End times shown in the expected results relate back to any of the datetime values in the sample data. Can you add more explanation please? Also, presumably Count = Rate (disparity between narrative and sample/expected)

Comment: `1/9/2022 10:00` and `1/9/2022 11:00` don't even show up in your sample data; where are they coming from in your expected results?

Comment: I just poached a slightly modified version of Lucero's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923295/how-can-i-truncate-a-datetime-in-sql-server

Comment: Can you explain the start- and end-time of that 90-row?

Comment: Is it possible to have a row that, say, starts at 14:03 and ends at 15:37? How would that be handled?

Comment: My apologies, experts. I was trying post a portion of the requirement to simplify, looks like that added the confusion. Full details have been updated, please let me know if any more clarifications required on the logic.

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte as

(

select Rate as Rate,dateadd(hour,datediff(HOUR,0,StartTime),0) as starttime, 
dateadd(HOUR,DATEDIFF(hour,0,endtime),0)  as EndTime 
from Row_Data

)

select sum(rate) as Rate,StartTime,Endtime from cte

group by StartTime,EndTime 

order by starttime desc
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Answer (score 0):

Something like (I'm assuming you made a typo in the sample expected data and the starts/ends are meant to be the 0th minutes)

```
SELECT SUM(Rate),
       Trunc_Start,
       Trunc_End
  FROM (
    SELECT dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, Start_Time), 0) AS Trunc_Start,
           dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, ENd_Time) + 1, 0) AS Trunc_End,
           Rate
      FROM SOME_TABLE
  )
GROUP BY Trunc_Start,
         Trunc_end
```

Answer (score 0):

select sum(Rate),StartTime ,EndTime from table
group by  StartTime ,EndTime

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)). Also, please have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) help page about how to format code properly.