# How to get only date part while using dateadd() and getdate()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I want to display records of last 4 months from current date.

I don't want to consider time

How can I get just date part from the below query?

```
where OrderDate >= DATEADD(month, -4, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Version of SQL server? 2008?

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427469/compare-dates-in-t-sql-ignoring-the-time-part

Comment: Sql server management studio 10.50 (SqlServer 2008 R2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the simple DATEDIFF function

```
where DATEDIFF(MM, OrderDate, GETDATE()) < 4
```

Comment: Using a function over a column (ie `OrderDate`) make it impossible for SQL Server to use existing indexes.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using SQL Server 2008, try converting `GETDATE()` to a `DATE` directly.

```
WHERE OrderDate >= DATEADD(month, -4, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df444/2

Comment: I can agree with your first, but why would you perform a conversion to varchar specifying a format that can be interpreted ambiguously and then let the system perform an implicit conversion back to `datetime`, where such ambiguity may produce incorrect results or errors?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - fair assumption. I have removed the latter.

Comment: Still getting date time as output...2013-10-25 15:52:31.000

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use the `DATE` type, there's the *old way*: convert the `DATETIME` value to `CHAR`, trim the hour components and then convert it back to `DATETIME`, so the hour components will be zeroed:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112), 112)
-- -----------------------
-- 2014-02-25 00:00:00.000
```

The important thing is to use the function over the scalar parameter (and **not** on the column) to allow the usage of existing indexes.