# SQL: How to compare dates while ignoring the time?

Tags: sql

How can I compare just the dates of timestamps while ignoring the times?

I just want to compare the month/date/year.  For example:

```
select * from Batch
where openingtime <> closingtime
```

The problem is that this will show too many batches, since it will include batches where `OpeningTime` and `ClosingTime` differ only in the time of day:

---

`OpeningTime = 2010-07-07 11:19:29.000`

---

`ClosingTime = 2010-07-07 19:19:22.000`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare dates in T-SQL, ignoring the time part](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427469/compare-dates-in-t-sql-ignoring-the-time-part)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cast both timestamps as dates

For SQL Server

```
Select * 
from Batch 
where cast(openingtime as date) <> cast(closingtime as date)
```

For Oracle

```
Select * 
from Batch 
where trunc(openingtime) <> trunc(closingtime)
```

Comment: what code can I add to so closingtime had to be after 3:00AM?

Comment: by after 3am would that mean that you want to count stuff milliseconds after 3am?

if so then 

in the where clause add:

    and datepart(hour, closingtime) >= 3

Answer (score 2):

Another way

```
Select * from Batch where      
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),openingtime,110<>CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),closingtime,110)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * from Batch where      
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),openingtime,110)<>CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),closingtime,110)

**There will be a closing bracket** @Miyamoto Musashi
```