# Comparing current date in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to check in a stored procedure a date in table if it is equal to Today's date.

```
  Code is 
    DECLARE @p0 datetime
    Set @p0 =GETDATE()
    Select * from testtable 
    where dateCol=@p0
```

This doesn't work it just gives empty rows. How can I accomplish that? Thanks

Comment: GETDATE() returns the date and time. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467103/ms-sql-date-only-without-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If dateCol is just the date, not DATETIME, you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE dateCol = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
SET @p0 = CONVERT(CHAR(10),GETDATE(),103)
```

`GETDATE()` returns the date and time.  You probably have records with todays date but not at this exact time.

Also you don't really need to store it in `@p0`. You could use the expression directly in the `WHERE` clause.